# Only actions taken are displayed on question while checking the history of Low Quality Posts review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

On Ask Ubuntu, when I try to view my Low Quality Posts review history and click on the action taken on questions, I can only see the actions taken and no preview of the question.

[Example 1](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/960752):

[image]

The question still exists on the site: [How can i fix the problem with the battery?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1156417/816190)

It seems question review history page is missing this HTML class:

```html
<div class="reviewable-post reviewable-post-post_id">
```

On the other hand, everything is working fine for answers.

Comment: Reproduced. Example here on this site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/65050

Comment: Repro'd [today on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/162412)

Comment: I recall this bug also happening when a user who doesn't have enough reputation to do the review looks at an entry for a question, even if the review hasn't finished yet. (I've now hit 2,000 rep on the site this happened on, so can no longer test it)

Comment: Now it seems to be happening on almost all recent LQP review on [math.se]: as you can check for youself: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1272909/recent-reviews-of-a-specific-type?type=3

Comment: This happened to me on Super User: https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/1017034

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed with the [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/295232). I revisited a Low Quality Posts review queue item for a question, and it is shown again, as it used to be before the bug:

[image]