# Visual design changes to the review queues

Tags: discussion, review, announcements

The [Public Platform team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349266/) would like to announce another release in a [series of planned work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351117/plans-for-updates-to-review-queues) for the Review queues. This release focuses on refreshing the queue user interface in preparation for further improvements to the user experience. Starting today, we will roll out these changes in three phases across the network.

### Roll-out plan

We have planned for these UI changes to ship in three distinct phases affecting specific queues across the network. We will update this post as each phase is rolled out.

|  | What | Where | When |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Phase 1** | • Home page (/review) • Close and reopen votes queue • Stats/History view • Steward badge | Meta Stack Exchange Meta Stack Overflow | **Shipped!** January 28, 2021 |
| **Phase 2** | • *Changes from Phase 1* • Suggested edits queue • Low quality posts queue • First posts queue • Late answers queue | SuperUser Ask Ubuntu | **Shipped!** February 16, 2021 |
| **Phase 3** | • *Changes from Phase 1 + 2* • Triage queue (SO only) • Help and improvement queue (SO only) | All network sites | **Shipped!** February 23, 2021 |

### UI changes to all queues

[image: updated close votes queue]

All review queues will be adopting a new user interface that focuses on providing reviewers with context to make deliberate, thoughtful decisions on review tasks. We shared an initial design proposal in our [product discovery phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346902/improving-review-queues-design-overview-i-onboarding-and-updating-workflows) and made sure to include that feedback into the final design.

#### Responsive/Mobile-friendly design

[image: new mobile view of close votes queue]

We utilized [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) to update the visual design in the review queues. As part of this update, we were also able to make the queues responsive and utilize mobile-friendly UI components.

#### Changes

- **Actions menu** -  We’ve removed the action buttons for a menu-style component. Selecting an action now requires a bit of pause and mitigates robo-reviewer behaviors we've seen in the past. Instructions are now always visible and associated with each action.
- **More context** - Users can now toggle between the review task and the necessary context (original question, answers, and comments) on the task page to assist in making educated decisions on a task. No need to open new browser tabs!
- **Vote controls and follow feature** - We heard from you that being able to vote directly on all tasks as well as the option to follow posts and receive updates on changes would help in the reviewing process. These features will be available in all queues.
- **Filter button** - We’re highlighting this feature (where it’s available) with a button and replacing the easily missed text-link.
- **Review count** - We’ve removed the badge progress bar in lieu of keeping track of how many tasks you can complete in a queue (don’t worry, the badge bar isn’t gone).

### Review home page

[image: updated review queues home page]

The review homepage has received a Stacks update as well, setting it up for forthcoming plans to create better onboarding for new reviewers. This page now provides a bit more information to new reviewers.

#### Changes

- Only the queues available/earned by the user are clickable
- Includes additional text about necessary reputation to earn access to new queues
- Available queues are prioritized to the top and then sorted by the number of tasks in each queue

### Additional updates

[image: updated history page]

[image: updated stats page]

All aspects of the Review queues are receiving some much needed design attention. Here a few more changes you can expect to see:

- There is more incentive to continue reviewing. The Steward badge can now be earned multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in each queue. If you have already completed 2,000 or more reviews, we will backfill any additional Steward badges that you have already earned. You can expect to see them accrue over the next few days.
- History view - Added and rearranged a few UI components so that users can better navigate and utilize the page
- Stats view - Updated badge progress bar

### Feedback

Please leave any feedback or bug reports related to this release below this post. We will be reviewing responses on this post for one month following Phase 3 (March 23, 2021). After March 23rd, please ask a new question to report any new issues.

Comment: You have Dark Mode on ... Meta Stack Exchange? I knew about Meta.SO from Catija's screenshots in the [tag:stacks-editor] announcement ...

Comment: @Glorfindel You sure that's not SO?

Comment: @Ollie first screenshot, that's https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331188/295232

Comment: What's behind the decision to show the "questions list" view of the post title, its asker, and ask date instead of the normal question view? Likewise, why are you injecting the meta information about the review item in between the title and the post body? Both of those decisions are confusing to me.

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah, I got that from the Meta logo in the top left.  That's odd.  Lisa, are you using a script or something, or... is there something going on?

Comment: Look at the dates and names in those screenshots, @Ollie / Glor - this is likely a local or dev-tier build running against a dump from the MSE database. Any theme can be selected in that context - dark-mode Physics, for instance. Which just leaves the question of why Lisa is NOT using dark-mode Physics?! 

Comment: Thanks for adding responsive design. I use the site (math.se) exclusively on mobile device and it was a real pain handling reviews .

Comment: Why did you make the avatars on the review queue so small?  They are largely un-recognizable now.

Comment: I think it would've been better if Phase 1 included an opt-in on Stack Overflow. Only ~900 users have access to the Close and reopen votes queues on Meta.SE and Mata.SO's queues are almost always empty :(

Comment: @41686d6564 While I share your enthusiasm for getting this on Stack Overflow, it makes more sense to preview it on a smaller site of core power users first. They have a unique opportunity with MSE and a 3k reputation threshold; users with that much rep on MSE are almost guaranteed to know the system *and* respect it... you run it on SO and now you have thousands and thousands of users with enough rep, most of whom won't respect or "know" the system well.

Comment: Can you please replace dark mode screenshots with light mode screenshots. It is impossible for me to read them and combination of large dark and bright surfaces makes it hard to even read the rest of the post.

Comment: The giant gap between the title and body of the question is jarring and confusing. The body follows from the title, so putting the reason for flagging between the two like you did is like putting it between the first and second paragraph of the question. Except this is worse in some sense, as the title is now part of an entirely different thing and doesn't appear to be the title of what appears below at all any more. That thing also duplicates the score and answer count.

Comment: @StephenRauch Probably because the user profile image is not relevant info to have for reviewing posts, and screen real estate is limited as it is

Comment: @TylerH, The avatar image is not directly relevant to reviewing items, but neither is most of the rest of the info on the review queue page.  In the end, all you really need is the queue name (link) and the number of work items available.

Comment: Wow, you can update the Review Queues but still cannot deliver site designs? Some sites have been waiting nearly five years to get their look feel updated as promised. You implemented a generic site design which was supposed to standardize and make easier the rollout of the designs. That was a few years ago now, too. So, just curious? You have time for this but not for site designs?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I understand your frustration and I know that it's difficult to be waiting for so long. But we can't make site designs at this point. We have major needs for improving very basic elements of our sites so that they function well and so that people understand how to use them. This change improves the review experience network-wide, site designs benefit a single site and are purely cosmetic. On smaller sites, the improvements to review may not be as important but these are still valuable changes.

Comment: @Catija Even cosmetics can be important. Just imagine there wouldn't be any specific site designs on the network.

Comment: @Trilarion it's not that they aren't important... but it's like trying to paint a house while the foundation is failing. Paint serves a purpose in protecting wood siding and making the house look approachable but I don't think anyone would argue that painting a house that has identical paint to the ones in the neighborhood but has foundation issues is the right choice - do you?

Comment: @Catija I understand where you are coming from but I can also understand Paulster2. To stay with analogies: there is a pandemics, but still people use cosmetics even though they are definitely not helping with anything important. It's just looks but even that matters. On the other hand, the old review dialog was kind of usable, failing foundations might be a bit too hard a description. Finally, if the foundations are failing and there is not even real paint on the walls, why is the owner not investing more? Is the business not profitable enough?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 They probably cannot deliver site designs *because* they are working on review queue updates (among other things). The review queues have been needing an overhaul for more than 5 years anyway. Sites can wait to have a new background image.

Comment: @TylerH "Sites can wait to have a new background image." I'm not completely sure about that. Maybe some users decide that participation is not enough fun if the background image isn't nice enough and go elsewhere.

Comment: Does the new version include the ability to flag low-quality spam, or do we still need to open a new window for that?

Comment: @Mark why would you want that? There's no way for a spam post to reach the low quality queue.

Comment: @Braiam, yes, there is: the system can automatically decide that a post is low-quality, or someone could flag it as "very low quality" instead of "spam".

Comment: Timeline seems a bit off, as it doesn't indicate the new suggested edit queue rolling out to MSO yet, although it has

Comment: Thanks a lot to those involved in implementing this change. I used the new system on math.se and it's a godsend for those who use site on a mobile device.

Comment: Hi @Lisa, now that I have had some time to play around with this on Stack Overflow (where 99.999% of my reviewing takes place), I have some thoughts on layout changes. With this rolled out and already having 75 answers over 3 pages, would you recommend I post that suggestion as an answer under this question, or as a new question here on MSE?

Comment: Answering for Lisa here @TylerH - we're following the answers to this question closely, so this is still the best place to share your thoughts.

Comment: The blue popup boxes are killing me. I *know* I just completed a review. It's particularly painful in the Android interface.

Comment: what really kills it for me is that now one has to make more clicks for the same action as before when reviewing, but well, that was called as a feature in the Changes section, so woah... yea, it suddenly appears to be good

Comment: Looks like the bug [In first post review, votes aren't validated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380802/4642212) still hasn’t been fixed. I was able to [submit a review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28557605) where I undid my vote outside of the queue before hitting “Submit”, but the voting arrow still showed as active. Not sure if this part, specifically, is necessary to fix, or how hard it would be, but there may be the possibility of abuse there.

Comment: @kristinalustig Are prior answers still being looked into here? I posted an answer two weeks before answers were closed off here and mine hasn't been responded to still. Should I repost it as a new question to make sure it gets attention?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yes - please do. sorry it got passed over, but submitting it as a new question is definitely the best way to get it looked at.

Comment: @kristinalustig Thanks; writing it now. Is this something that I can/should do with old feedback answers that were posted within the question's deadline but didn't receive a response for a year or more, for other announcements?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog In general we try to look at all feedback until the deadline, as you mentioned - I can take the blame for this one, as I was the one mostly going through and fixing things here... I don't remember why I didn't get to it! But yes, if you have any feedback that you want to make sure is seen and it hasn't been acknowledged in an announcement like this in a reasonable time, by all means surface it as its own question.

Answer (score 117):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the old review queues, when you visit [a completed review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/76892), you can just click Next to proceed. Now you have to check the radio button *and* click 'Submit'. Can this be just a single click please, just like 'Skip' also is in the new queue? My touchpad will thank you for that.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's very annoying. Should be one-button action, like "skip". Next isn't even an action, while Skip *technically* is!

Comment: This issue appears to have been fixed. When I go back to a review I have completed, I now see a blue "Next Task" button inside the blue banner. (Just like in the new banner after an audit.)

Answer (score 66):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Not sure if it’s a bug or deliberate change, but something that has been tripping me over and over while viewing the history is that the placement of the editor’s user card looks more prominent and can be mistaken as the OP.

[image]

P.S. Well, I think I have to get accustomed to now... (cue [XKCD #1172](https://xkcd.com/1172/))

Comment: Good feedback - we were talking yesterday about modifying that design to include just a small avatar and user name beside the edited text and moving it back left. I'm not going to add the status-planned tag just yet but we are thinking about how to fix that.

Comment: @kristinalustig Any update on this discussion? Would really love to see the author info back in a usercard at the bottom right just like the normal/organic question view shows it (and have the editor usercard in the bottom middle of the question).

Comment: @TylerH We haven't started work on this yet but Brian added it to our backlog with some notes - he and I will chat about it this week or next and figure out the best way to proceed. We'll update this answer when we do have something to share!

Comment: @kristinalustig Awesome, glad to hear it. It immediately and consistently trips me up in the queue 0:-)

Comment: Thanks for the report. We've gone ahead and added back in the "asked by" card at the bottom, which will keep the information where you're used to seeing it. We weren't saving any vertical space anyway because the edited card was still the full card. We may go ahead and make some adjustments to this in the future, but we'll be sure to keep this particular issue in mind as we make future changes, and we'll work to keep the placement of various bits of information consistent. The update will be in the next build, either later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 49):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> The Steward badge can now be earned multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in each queue.

[image]

The badge descriptions do not reflect this and need updating

Comment: We can't update these strings on a per-site basis, so we're in a position of having to decide to leave them as-is for the sites getting early access to this new functionality - or - going ahead and changing the text everywhere. We discussed it and, since the change will be true eventually, we're going to change the string network-wide now and wait to award the badges when the change launches to the network.

Comment: Ahh, now I've read this, it all makes sense the recent odd system behavior.

Comment: It's very nice to have this badge change buried under "Visual design changes to the review queues" titled post

Comment: @Kos: There have been two other posts dedicated to the topic: [Award criteria of the steward badge changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360270/195817 "Gold badge parity and balance – award criteria of the steward badge changes") and [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/195817 "Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times — backfill details").

Comment: @Scott I feel there a lot more which is happened because people had questions and they didn't have answers

Comment: With a significant amount of feedback- I suspect that it's just kinda lost in the clutter. I for one find the sheer number of answers overwhelming

Comment: @Scott Those posts were made a day after this post (one by a normal user stumbling upon it), and this post is the one whose subject also brought the multi-award change to the environment, so it's not an unreasonable criticism that this post should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 42):

### Immediate reactions

(no posts in the queues, so going off screenshots):

- Love seeing the presentation of posts being brought back into line with question pages. In particular, the stats at the top are a lot harder to miss than the sidebar on the old UI.
- Love the responsive design - phones are an ideal interface for review, as it involves lots of small tasks; perfect for standing in line at the grocery store.
- I personally hate dropdowns for actions: they default to hiding what is available. On mobile they have the additional issue of being modal: I can't both select an action *and* scroll through what I'm acting on. And I use an Android phone, where they're actually kinda usable; from what I've seen, this will be a real problem on iOS devices, where they present a weird scrollable UI seemingly inspired by "The Big Wheel" from the old Price is Right gameshow.

  [image: an iOS select picker next to that wheel from the gameshow]

  Remember: the goal here is for folks to make informed decisions based on a careful examination of the post being reviewed - anything that separates the action from the post risks working against that.
- I'm a little bit concerned about the position of the task description itself: putting it between the post stats and the post seems... Odd? It actually took me a minute to find it.

### Other thoughts

The make-or-break for this is gonna be how folks actually use it. Voting in particular is potentially problematic: when we first tried that, it resulted in a MASSIVE skew for voting on Stack Overflow.

I'm happy to see that you intend to test this on Ask Ubuntu and Super User - they get enough traffic to potentially flush out some issues. I'm unclear on whether you're rolling out the phase 1 changes there *before* you do on Stack Overflow.

Regardless, it will be critical that you monitor behavior after this goes live. Not just how many reviews are done, but the breakdown of their disposition and side-effects. For example, if more First Posts are upvoted *and* later closed, there's something weird happening; if more posts going through the close queue are being downvoted *and* answered, there's an issue. Etc.

Looking forward to trying this out on my phone once it's live on a real site!

Comment: SO will be part of Phase 3, so it won't get any of these changes until we've seen them in action on SU and AU. :)

Comment: "it resulted in a MASSIVE skew for voting on Stack Overflow" is there any reference of that? What was the problem?

Comment: Yeah, the dropdown isn't really nice on iOS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnl7b.jpg - you have to click 'Done' before you see the change. And the 'action bar' floats all the way to the bottom if you scroll.

Comment: Is that... One single screen @Glorfindel? Or did you paste together two separate ones? It is very confusing.

Comment: Sure, @Braiam - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything

Comment: One single screen, iPhone 11 / iOS 14

Comment: Wow. Just... Wow. Every time someone shows me a `<select>` from iOS, there's something new to facepalm about.

Comment: What does it look like on Android? I don't really have a strong opinion on the select from iOS, but I've only used iOS and desktops.

Comment: @jrh on Android [the dropdown is shown as a modal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTBK6.png)

Comment: Oi, SU is a real site :D

Comment: It's not live yet on SU, @JourneymanGeek! (Not that I have enough rep there anyway though)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. ah... yeah, that is much better. For a native app that's fixable for iOS by just not using a dropdown and using a table view instead (even Apple's own system apps don't use the big wheel thing for every "select a thing from a list") but I bet SO is stuck using something more generic and they may have been "helpfully" railroaded into using "everyone's favorite" default native option.

Answer (score 29):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When trying out the filter in the Close Votes review queue on Meta Stack Exchange, the system suggests me to filter on [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [java](/questions/tagged/java). The queue is empty right now, but I'm pretty sure it will remain empty forever if I filter on that. Please use the current site's top tags or none at all.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this report - all fixed!

Comment: Thanks - but [tag:badge] should be [tag:badges], I guess. That's the master.

Comment: The updated code is either using a site setting where the desired tag examples are listed, or grabbing from the top tags for each site, in that order. It looks like it's actually just perfectly cutting off the "s" at the end of the input: if you inspect the element it does say "badges." Since the length of the placeholder will change per-site, I'm not going to make any adjustments to the length of the input.

Comment: Ah, you're right, now I see it too.

Answer (score 25):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Could rollbacks in the edit summary show the revision number and not the raw text of the revision, as shown here (from the Reopen Votes queue):

[image]

So it looks like this:

[image]

That would be much more helpful than a bunch of characters.

Comment: I would say this is a bug rather than a feature request.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated Possibly.  I've never seen a rollback in a queue before, so I couldn't say.

Comment: @Ollie can you please give more details about where you are seeing this text appear (your screenshot chops off the context), which queue?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Updated my answer.

Comment: This has been completed

Comment: Thanks @YaakovEllis.  [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/76876), for anyone who wants to check.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For duplicate closure, it seems the link to the duplicate is not shown on the completed Close Vote review item now. E.g. [a random completed review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/60808) which [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317614/maximum-size-and-bandwidth-of-se-voting-telegraphy-is-this-a-known-thing) is currently a dupe of [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

[image]

Compare to the current Close Vote review on other sites

[image]

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I suppose the "All reviews" should show all the reviews in that queue (privilege for >10k).

[image]

However, clicking it just reloads the page appending a `?skipped=false` (if it doesn't exist) parameter. That button should be either removed or disabled for <10k.

Comment: Thanks for the report - I fixed this, it should be a much better experience now.

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The revision comment is truncated. For example on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359566) question ([review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/76725)) the revision comment is:

> Active reading [http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance (the last section) ].

But what is actually shown is this:

[image]

Comment: Related [bug](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5585/176217) on ruSO and [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303001/339911)

Comment: This has been completed

Answer (score 19):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

### Make better use of the screen real-estate.

My favourite view to review in is the side by side view, usually the markdown version of it. As it currently stands the site is served with a max-width instead of being totally responsive. This is already painful on some long posts without many paragraphs, but in this review view it is even worse.

Take a look at this screenshot, of the entire width of my monitor:
[image]

The screen is divided in about 5 equal parts, of which only 2 out of the 5 carry meaningful content, namely the side by side diffs. When reviewing long posts this becomes extra painfull, as then half of the screen will be empty (The first and last column, and half of the column that carries the actions box):

[image]

Can we move the actions box back on top, so I can use at least 3/5th of my screen to view the content that is actually of interest.

Comment: Re: this and your other request, I actually am working on a request (not sure how to post it yet-- as an answer or a separate question since this is now fully rolled out). Compare the current rollout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoBih.png with my 15 minute re-layout effort (WIP): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr4ss.png

Comment: Not sure what you would expect to be put under the "Actions" section, btw. The old layout also had an actions section on the top right and nothing below it IIRC.

Comment: @TylerH I don't really see any major differences between your two screenshots.

Comment: @TylerH I was thinking to put the actions as a horizontal sticky bar on top, so you could make the two diffs colums wider.

Comment: I made a series of changes. You may need to open each image in a new tab and swap back and forth to compare them; should be pretty obvious then. I removed several superfluous items that each took up their own "row" of space on the page. The main result is that the question content actually starts on the top half of the page now instead of 60-70% of the way down the screen.

Comment: Yeah on mobile it was hard to see, but on a real monitor its obvious @TylerH. I think removing the "Learn More" info is not the best, but does save some space. Especially moving that banner with the filter and your remaining reviews further up to helps a lot.

Comment: Yeah for sure; in my personal env with those user styles applied I have a couple notes in comments along the lines of "this should probably return, but I need JS to make it work well/look pretty" since the mockup I made was just CSS-based for time. At any rate, I just posted an answer here suggesting all these changes and explaining each of them in depth. We'll see how it goes!

Comment: Related: [diffs are too narrow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361331/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah you're right, on second glance that is more or less the same. I just didn't know what to think of that answer.

Comment: If I could upvote this multiple times I would. With such thin columns I now find myself scrolling/panning horizontally code blocks alot more to ascertain what suggested edits were made.

Comment: See my comment on this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361378/344828 but basically this would require much more substantial changes to the site that we're not currently prepared to make. We may revisit it in the future. Thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 17):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When hovering over the date the question was asked, I'd expect a tooltip with the exact date (like almost everywhere else you see a relative timestamp) but not in the new review queue UI:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There's a small UI bug I noticed in Close Votes on SO. Below "Not suitable for this site", it says "subreason.InputTitle"; I assume that's not what it's supposed to say. This is only noticable with any of the "A community-specific reason" close reasons.

[image: Really awesome picture]

This bug is also visible on Math SE, and likely all other sites with community-specific close reasons.

[image: Another really awesome picture]

(Thanks to KReiser for screenshot and confirmation this also affects Math.SE)

Comment: This can also be seen on Math.SE for one of it's community specific close reasons [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGQh9.png). It looks like it may affect every community-specific close reason.

Comment: Also previously reported on MSO: [Close vote queue, flagged as showing "subreason.InputTitle"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405491/4642212).

Comment: This also shows up on Academia.SE [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/4SKFzDc.png) an example with multiple close reasons.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the catch. We had a missing @ sign in there - this should be fixed in the next build (likely a bit later today).

Answer (score 16):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> This is implemented. If community-specific close reason votes exist on the item, they will be shown indented underneath the main close reason. These will always be shown (departure from current functionality where it is only shown if you click on a *more* button). - Yaakov

### Not possible to see which community-specific close reason a question was flagged for in the close queue, if the question has close flags but no votes

In the old design of the review queue, if a question was flagged as *Not suitable for this site* (i.e. "off-topic", "A community-specific reason", etc.), it was possible to click the "more" link to expand the reason and see which specific sub-reasons under that umbrella the question had been placed into review for. This list included *both* sub-reasons from users with the close voting privilege casting actual close votes *and* those chosen by users who don't have enough rep to vote to close casting a flag to close:

> [image: Review showing a question flagged as "Needs debugging details"]

<sup>(credit to [Ryan M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165261/ryan-m) for the screenshot)</sup>

However, in the new review interface, there doesn't seem to be a way to see the specific reason(s) which have been chosen by users without enough rep to cast close votes casting flags:

> [image]

There is another way to view sub-reasons others have selected, by opening the closing dialog, but that only includes sub-reasons chosen by *voters*, not by flaggers, so this means that if there are only flags and no votes the dialog will be completely empty, and even if someone voted, there's no way to see if a flagger chose a different sub-reason from the voter(s).

Can a way to see which sub-reasons under *Not suitable for this site* have been selected *including* by recommend closure flaggers please be added to the close queue?

Comment: This has been completed. See notes above.

Answer (score 15):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I've had a chance to play with the Close Vote Review Queue a bit now on Stack Overflow where the overwhelming bulk of my reviewing activity occurs. My main takeaway is that there are some good functionality improvements (yay for letting us up/down vote in the close vote queue!), the tradeoff is a very expensive one: screen space

I see *a lot* of (in my humble opinion) unnecessary/redundant content on the page, and the end result is that the actual content of the page is pushed down for me past the halfway point of the screen (reference: I have 24" monitors at 1920x1080 resolution):

(and I actually set the top bar to `display: none` for these screenshots, so imagine everything is even further down the screen).

[image: screenshot of close vote queue highlighting how far down the page]

As you can see by the arrows and horizontal lines, we have to track wayyy down the screen just to get to the point of queue; all the content outside of the question title and body is not going to change from item to item, and most of it is not stuff we need to see *ever*, so why are they taking up so much real estate?

Here's the same screenshot with number labels for a list of suggested changes below: [image]

1. We don't need this link. If someone wants to go back to the questions page, they can click the existing Stack Overflow logo link about 50px above this and go back to the home page, which is `/questions` for anyone who is logged in. Likewise we already have the top menu option for review queues available if we want to go to the All Review Queues page. One extra click is not worth saving if the cost is 50px of valuable vertical screen space.
2. Same as above; we know what the close vote review queue is, and it's amply explained by other sections of the page as well... the flag/close banner, the URL, the 'review' UI, the 'Action' menu items on the right, etc.. I'd rather see users taken to the privilege page or a FAQ page the first time they click on the specific review queue than have this take up yet another 50-75px of screen space, if anything.
3. Why is this on its own line? Especially if you expand the size of the container to not be so small (see item #6) there should be plenty of space to move this up to the line above.

   3a. (Not pictured) Why is the "Filter" menu not a modal that appears outside the document flow? As it is, it pushes the page down unnecessarily when it's open. It's a small thing, but just feels like an obvious 'miss' in the execution here.
4. Not convinced we need this information... at least, we definitely don't need the question score, because it's shown on the very next line where I can actually vote on it/click to break out the full up/down vote information. I suspect that this entire row was just copied from the /questions page due to that being the most portable location for getting that info. All we *need* to see in this line is the question title. There is some use to seeing the number of answers (mostly in being able to *see **and vote on*** said answers from the queue)... so that bit I'm still on the fence about. The OP name and rep and ask date belongs at the bottom right of the question, but that's a separate bug/request here already being tracked/reviewed.
5. Again, we don't really need this info/option, at least not for the Close Vote queue; what answers a question has, or whether it has any in the first place, are irrelevant to whether the question is close-worthy. The *only* exception I can think of here is in the case of deciding which question should be duped as a target of another, but that's a case where you'll want to be looking at each question on the /questions/ page anyway rather than in the queue.
6. The width of the main container element is 1100px. But with the sidebar force-hidden by the new layout, we could easily expand this up to 1200px to reclaim some wasted gutter space and show a more "normal"-width container. I'm sure this change would be great across all review queues, but especially so for the suggested edit queue, where diffs are shown side-by-side.
7. (Not pictured) I also removed the "Review the following question" header element; again it's obvious we need to review this question, because we're *in the review queue* and this is the question on the page...

Taking all those things into consideration, I made a quick mockup with the Stylus add to demonstrate what this would look like (again, I'm focused on the Close Vote review queue here):

(NB: I have since re-added a grey HR/border between the question title and question body, but it isn't visible in this screenshot. Imagine there is one):

[image: mock-up of new/improved CV Queue page layout]

If you compare the 1st or 2nd image in a tab vs this 3rd one in a separate tab and swap back and forth, you can see there's a *lot* more space available in my modified version for the actual meat & potatoes of the page: the question being reviewed.

And just for those who might want to take that layout and run with it in their own user styles, here's the code I have that makes these changes:

```css
div.container { /* making the page container a more reasonable width. */
    max-width: 1200px !important;
}
.s-page-title--text > nav { /* hide the nav menu at the top.  */
    display: none;
}
.s-page-title--text  p.s-page-title--description { /* hide the description of the vote queue. */
    display: none;
}
.s-page-title + div { /* set parent element to relative */
    position: relative;
}
.s-page-title + div > div.grid--cell { /* move the filter options to the top */
    position: absolute;
    top: -68px;
    left: 250px;
}
div.js-review-task div.js-review-content h2:not(.popup-title-container) { /* hides instructions on what this page is for. */
    display: none;
}
#js-review-filter-id { /* set the filter option menu to be a modal instead of pushing the screen down */
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0px;
}
article.s-post-summary > ul { /* removing meta information */
    display: none;
}
article.s-post-summary { /* fixing row size due to grid properties */
    grid-template-columns: auto;
}
div.js-review-task > div > div > div:first-of-type + div:not(#panel-question) { /* hides the answers toggle menu option; unnecessary for the CV Queue */
    display: none;
}
div.js-review-task > div aside.js-review-instructions ~ div.grid--cell {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4a4e51;
}
div.post-signature { /* moves 'edited by' usercard to bottom-center of question instead of bottom-right to reduce confusion */
    flex: 3;
}
aside.js-review-instructions div.s-notice p { /* removing all the extra space for telling me I passed an audit item, part 1 */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
aside.js-review-instructions div.s-notice button {  /* removing all the extra space for telling me I passed an audit item, part 2 */
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good direction to go in, particularly in combination with other changes mentioned in other answers here.

Comment: Your point 6 I explicitly requested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361378/361484) (just as a reference).

Comment: As to keeping the user info above the question, I'd prefer a normal usercard below the post, as you describe, where everyone is already trained to look for it. While my first preference is a normal usercard, I'd rather see nothing identifying the user than having the user, reputation, and badges take pride of place above the post. The review queue moving them to above the post is a strong indication that they should matter for the review. In reality, who the author is and their reputation should not even be a consideration in almost all reviews, so being so *very* prominent is detrimental.

Comment: @Makyen Agreed on the usercard; I didn't bother making that change because **1)** it would require JS to adjust the HTML (at least dynamically. I could have done with CSS if I were just making the change for these screenshots alone), and **2)** the #1 or #2 scoring answer on this question is already specifically about the confusion there and requests putting it back where it belongs, and I believe the team has already been reviewing it internally for at least a month.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all this up, we really appreciate it. Just wanted to say that we're not ignoring it, I'm gathering up all of the design-related feedback/requests in this post and chatting with Lisa (the designer) this week to figure out how we want to approach any changes. I'll keep y'all updated.

Comment: @kristinalustig sure thing; I figure with *90 responses* y'all have your hands a little full... :-) PS - I've updated some of the thoughts above that I meant to circle back on after even more time in the queue. I haven't provided an updated screenshot of what my queue looks like only because I can't access that question again with that banner anymore... so it wouldn't be an "apples to apples" comparison, but I'm happy to provide one if an up-to-date reference point is of interest to you, Lisa, et al.

Comment: Updates: Lisa and I spoke and determined that we could make a couple of quick fixes to begin to address this usage of vertical space that you and a few others have mentioned. First, we're cutting out the breadcrumbs on the review pages. There're already several ways to get back to the queues dashboard and to the question page, and you're right that vertical space comes at a premium. We're exploring other ideas that I'm going to try to implement (condensing the top navigation, for example) but I can't guarantee that I'll have the time right away, so for now I'll leave the status-review.

Comment: @kristinalustig when reviewing context is crucial. Please, on the answer view include the question. You can't say a link-only answer should be deleted if the question asks for it.

Comment: @Braiam that seems like something that should be its own answer since it's specific to another queue type (this one does have some general items, but also has some specific CV-queue pieces).

Comment: Just wrapping up loose ends here - we made all the changes we intended to make based on your feedback at this time. Thanks for writing it up for us!

Comment: @kristinalustig you marked this [status-completed], however I don't see point 6 implemented.

Comment: @Luuklag I interpret kristina's comment "we made all the changes we *intended to make*"  to indicate anything not implemented from this feedback post will simply... not be implemented, as unfortunate as I may find that, personally :-)

Comment: @kristinalustig Thank you for implementing some of these suggested changes! Hope to see more improvements to the queue layout and functionality in the future (still anxiously awaiting the improved filtering options advertised previously!).

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In Reopen votes queue actions are not ordered in logical way.

"Reopen" and "Edit and Reopen" actions should be grouped together. "Leave closed" should be first action on top or last action on the bottom.

Current layout is rather confusing.

[image: Actions Image]

Comment: Good catch, this was largely accidental, and these will be reordered back to their original order in the next build, coming today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On screens with widths less than 640px (e.g. my iPhone 11) the daily stats are hidden:

[image]

There seems to be enough space; this is how it looks like a few pixels wider:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - we'd originally done this because the filter summary that appears next to the filter can get really long. I adjusted the review progress so that it stacks at narrow widths and the filter summary adjusts a bit more naturally. Should be much better now!

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

### Increase the max-width of the review screen to include the width of the left-nav bar

Here is a screenshot of both the regular site, and the review page at full width, 100% zoom. As you can see the screen real-estate used for content of the review page is smaller. Both the review-page and the contentblock (including the right sidebar) of the mainpage have a max width set of 1100 px.

Seeing there is no left-nav on review screens can we please increase the width of the review screen with the width of the left-nav.

[image]

Comment: Agreed; seeing a page with less than 1200px *at least* of used space is very irksome... basically half the page is unused right now and there's a massive amount of scrolling required to see most questions.

Comment: Thanks for considering at least @kristinalustig

Comment: After talking through this request with the design team, we've determined that no pages across the site get any wider than this 1100px mark. Therefore, making this change is a bigger undertaking, both technically and philosophically, and for now we're going to status-declined it. I do appreciate the report, and we'll possibly revisit this sometime in the future.

Comment: Thx for your reply, although I wholehartedly disagree @kristinalustig. I'll be raising a separate Meta discussion about this stance in the coming days when I find the time.

Answer (score 12):

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> We have come full circle on this. The notice has been moved above the question metadata, and the tab buttons (Task/Answer/Revision, etc) are now below the question metadata, directly above the area that the affect.

Based just on this [UI mockup in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bos2Q.png), the box at the top with the "This question has been flagged as" message seems out-of-place:

[image: mockup in question]

Wouldn't it be better to swap that box and the post title? Right now, the post looks disjointed, with the post title and body/details separate from each other.

Can it be like this instead?

[image: swap reason and post title]

In the [previous mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7abvk.png) in the post "[Improving Review Queues - Design overview I: Onboarding and updating workflows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346902/756727), that's how it was shown. Was there are reason for the change in this current mockup? I think swapping it back would result in a more coherent read: "This is your review task, this is why this post is in the queue (because it was flagged as *reason*), then here is the post title and body/description."

Furthermore, after I mocked-up this swapping, it now looks like the vote counter is redundant, and could possibly be simplified into:

[image: remove duplicate vote counter]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We are going to be switching the position of the notice. The vote count will stay as-is. Even though it is redundant in this view, the question header is used in many other views within reviews, a good number of which show things like answers, revisions, and other things that would not include the current question score. We want to keep this section consistent, even at the cost of redundancy in this one instance.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I haven't had the chance to see the other views (just this screenshot). It makes sense to keep views consistent across the different reviews.

Comment: You can see one of the views by clicking on the link for [Answers] above the "Review the following question" link.

Comment: After further consideration, we are not going to go ahead with changes here. Currently, that notice section serves as a nice visual separator between the question metadata on the top, and the content section below. Moving it above the question necesitates further redesign work that we would like to avoid right now. And this also might be more of a case of something to get used to. Can potentially be revisited later, going to stay this way for now.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I consider the title to be part of the content, but it’s separated. Visually, this feels quite messy, to be honest.

Comment: Agreed w/ Gino and Sebastian, the title is part of the question, and it's already how the queue is organized. There's no reason to change this and split the question into two different areas of the screen, displayed from different data sources to boot.

Comment: The fix is in. Please see note in the post above

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the new UI / visual design, when you go to a review page
and there are queues that you aren’t allowed to access yet,
it says “Awarded at 3k” (or whatever number is appropriate),
with the trophy icon (the same one that’s used
for the “Recent Achievements” dropdown):

[image: new review queue visual design]

This seems to be very peculiar and inappropriate language. 
Nothing gets “awarded” when you reach and exceed the threshold
for admission to a review queue. 
The old wording, “You need at least 3k reputation to review close votes.”,

[image: old review queue visual design]

was perfectly fine.

---

P.S. In the announcement (i.e., *this* “question”), you say

> #### Changes
>
> - Only the queues available/earned by the user are clickable
> - Includes additional text about necessary reputation
>   to earn access to new queues
> - Available queues are prioritized to the top
>   and then sorted by the number of tasks in each queue

The first and third bullets are not changes —
it’s always been that way (at least as far as I can remember). 
And the second one, as shown above, seems to be outright false;
the new design has *less* text about reputation necessary
to ‘earn’ access to queues than the current design.

Comment: The privilege is awarded at 3k reputation.   "Awarded" seems like fine language to me.   "Privilege awarded" could be clearer (but longer.)

Comment: It is more confusing not to have units on the "3k".   "3k" what?  Penguins?   It should be "3k reputation" or "3k rep."

Comment: More likely unicoins or Zorkmids.  Or perhaps waffles.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind using the wording but I agree with Scott that this is making it sound a bit like a superlative when it's really a janitorial duty.

Comment: Thanks for the report - I added back in the word "reputation" at the end so it's clear that you do not have to make 3000 waffles to get access to the queue. :-)

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Let us vote on answers as well (they need some love, too)! Here's how an answer looks like from the "Answers" tab:

[image]

Comment: Since current Phase 1 is strictly about Close Vote (questions) review, I'm not sure voting on answers is relevant. Later on Phase 2 and 3, answers should already be possible to be voted while being reviewed.

Comment: We've implemented voting across queues and post types, so you should be able to vote as soon as the next build is out, either today or tomorrow. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On narrow screens, the user names and their review counts on the review stats (e.g. [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)) occupy the same space:

[image]

Comment: This has been fixed

Comment: Aha! You even fixed the issue [on the daily stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRIIw.png) too!

Comment: Yes, they use the same user profile control, so this fix will be in effect wherever that is used in a narrow width.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The 'Next' option and the 'Edit' option have rather useless tooltips. The other options (at least in the Close Votes review queue) don't. Can they be removed?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we have the View Count show a shortened version (e.g., 190K), instead of all these numbers:

[image]

And then have a tooltip to show the exact number, to be more consistent with the look on the actual post?  It’ll look better for posts with 1M+ views.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the Suggested Edits queue, when looking at a review task, the link to the post will always route to the parent question even if the suggested edit applies to an answer on that question.

As an example, on [this review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/77069), clicking this text:

[image]

Takes me to [the parent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/622284) instead of taking me to where I expect it should take me, [the answer that the suggested edit was proposed on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360785/622284).

Could this link be changed to point to the answer instead?

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### Allow opt-in for sites that haven't rolled out the new UI to everyone

I'd love to be able to help test this out in the earlier phases, but there are virtually never any questions in the queue on MSO and MSE, and I don't have 3k rep on Ask Ubuntu or Super User.

Could it be possible for users on other sites to opt into the new UI (similar to the opt-in for the new editor) before their site is converted over for everyone?

Comment: We're not planning to offer opt-in on the review queues, as the functionality will be rolled out networkwide in a few short weeks.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Makes sense, fair enough.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @AnitaTaylor It would be nice if the February 16 launch to some sites was pre-poned, though, so there's more time to test the system out on a site with review audits enabled. The current system means there's only one week for us to report issues with audits before it's launched network-wide.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog The goal is to roll this out networkwide as soon as possible vs. having a prolonged review period where some sites have it and some sites don't. There will be a full month after it launches networkwide where we will be logging and fixing bugs

Answer (score 9):

This may not pertain to the intent of the current review queue makeovers.  But I have been longing to see some functionality to enable a reviewer to directly link to a moderator, particularly in the suggested edit review queue.  (What I am about to request, can be disabled for audit reviews).

I review primarily on [math.se], and occasionally on [matheducators.se].  I have encountered efforts to "edit a post" to threaten the OP of the post, including vandalism and outright hostile name-calling and threats, particularly offered from "anonymous user".  Also, I notice a username repeatedly making exceptionally trivial edits.  It would greatly simplify matters if there were a mechanism, within the review, to flag for moderator attention.

Currently, to contact a mod, I have to flag the post on which the attempted edit was made, and in my flag description, copy the review (requiring me to go to review history to get the link) into the description, etc, often multiple times for ongoing problems.

I very much like the changes thus far described, and do not want to ask too much of developers now, but I would be ecstatic if such a "flag moderator" functionality were added to the suggested edit review  queue.

Comment: This is a fundamentally good idea, but out of scope for this project.  It would be a good idea to repost this as its own question so it can get broader discussion and attention.

Comment: Sure, @Brian.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

I think this would be the perfect opportunity to enhance the automated "review testing" system by adding a "minor" new button.

Right now, when the system thinks you made the wrong choice, it tells you that you messed up, and to do better in the future. Then there is a single button `I understand` that you have to click to continue on the review queue.

I suggest to add a button:

`I understand, but object the automated decision` (wording to be improved), with a text field to provide a comment why that is.

**Rationale**: we all know that the automated system is far from perfect, and it is really annoying when it presents you questions that it got wrong. When that happens, it frustrates the reviewers, and worse, it leaves a "stain" on their resume. The later might matter or not, but when it matters, it is on the reviewer to remember when the system messed up to be able to "prove innocence" (and when you really do A LOT of reviews, that is a real problem).

So, giving the reviewer an opportunity to *object* would enable:

- the system to "drop" bad test questions faster
- the system to keep track of objects, so in case there is ever a need for a human moderator to check the review history, those objections are more prominent

**Addendum**: the aspect of "this is a bad *test* question" might even be worth a button when the user *passes* the test. Happened to me repeatedly, too: to figure "this is a test question, and I should react that way, although the specific question at hand actually should have been treated in another way".

Comment: That "stain" matters more than one might think: if one's been suspended from review in the past 30 days, and they fail a *single* audit, they'll immediately be re-suspended.

Comment: This is a bigger feature than the scope of the project, and probably deserves to be its own question/discussion.  I'll _try_ to put in some time this sprint to see if I can measure how pervasive an issue this is (e.g., # of seasoned reviewer failing audits, audit templates with multiple failures, etc).

Comment: @BrianNickel I understand that part, but then: the deficiencies of the auto-testing system are really annoying, so anything that helps with that would be good!

Comment: *This*. For a long time I have wanted some sort of "appeal audit decision" or "flag bad audit example" mechanism.

Comment: @BrianNickel For reference: [a feature request I filed a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351160/377214) with some more info.

Comment: Holy mackerel 150% this. It's so tedious to have to go to a question's normal page and up/downvote it and close vote/delete vote it when I encounter a bad audit item to try and remove it as an audit item.

Comment: We're not going to have time to dig into audits more right now, but I've added this to the team's backlog and we're going to do a more thorough look into it when we're addressing workflow changes a bit later on in the project. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: We were hoping to address this issue as part of the last phase of our Review Queues overhaul. However, it quickly became apparent when diving into this request and others related to audits, that improving audits is its own project that's going to require more user research, as well as potential Community Manager/Moderator process changes. We see the merit in this suggestion and have marked it as status-deferred. Improving audits is not on our [Q3 2021 roadmap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368049/) and won't be prioritized in the near future, but we have added it to our backlog.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but not surprising. As the audit system is one big project if change is wanted to be helpful!

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When reviewing answers in the First Posts review queue, sometimes there's a tab 'Other answers (x)'. When you click it, the tab heading is repeated, while it's not for the other tabs ('Answer' and 'Question'). I don't think it's necessary and it's eating away a bit of screen real estate. Can it be removed please?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

In the suggested edits queue, the username of the person who proposed the edit is written with tiny letters. Their reputation is also hidden.

[image]

This is some important piece of information and you should give it more emphasis by placing it somewhere in the top - perhaps here?

[image]

(after renaming "the following question" to "the following edit" - [bug](/questions/tagged/bug))

Comment: The "the following question"/"the following answer" bug was also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361012/284827).

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [review](/questions/tagged/review) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

(Before I was aware of this announcement post, I already posted this as a meta bug question here: [Submit button not working anymore in new review queue layout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405486/submit-button-not-working-anymore-in-new-review-queue-layout))

I encountered a bug in the *Triage* review queue. I can click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button when I select one of the options "Looks OK" or "Needs community edit" (which do not have suboptions) but not if I select "Needs author edit". In the past, a dialog opened in which I was asked to specify the detailed reason (e.g. "Needs details or clarity" or "Needs more focus"), but now, I am stuck at this point. So either the dialog is not displayed or it is located somewhere off-screen, I guess.

The only thing that happens is that the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button is enabled, but when I click it, nothing happens (both in Firefox on a Linux desktop PC as well as on Chrome on Android).

[image]

Some other users apparently do not encounter this behavior and have speculated that it might have something to do with their privileges (see comments under the linked question above).

**Edit:** Before, I reported that the same behavior occurred when selecting the "Flag" option. After double checking, I found that this is in fact not correct. When selecting "Flag", the dialog to specify the type of flag correctly appears after clicking <kbd>Submit</kbd>. So, the problem only occurs for the option "Needs author edit".

Comment: Have you run out of flags?, that's the only cause I can think of

Comment: @Nick I'm running into the same bug on SO, and I still have around 90 flags left for the day. The "Flag" option still works fine, it's just the "Needs author edit" option that's failing.

Comment: Check the browser console and Network inspector. Anything interesting there?

Comment: @SebastianSimon There is no activity at all in console or network inspector when I select one of the options.

Comment: @buddemat Including clicking `Submit`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I just double checked. If I click `Submit` after having selected the *Flag* option, the dialog to select the type of flag appears correctly (I could have sworn that wasn't the case before, but maybe I'm mistaken here. Will edit the post). For the *Needs author edit* option, nothing happens at all, when I click `Submit`.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this bug! We've figured out why this is happening and are working on a fix right now - I'll post here again once the fix is shipped with more of an explanation.

Comment: Same here with Chrome and Firefox on Win10. Nothing happens with Needs author edit and submit ...
observed already yesterday, retested today

Comment: I put this in the original post as well, but: in order for Recommend Close (or Needs Author Edit) to function properly, the js relies on a (hidden) close link in the post menu to be present on the page. However, we only included the close link for users who had close permissions. So when you tried to perform that action, it just failed silently because it couldn't find the button to click. I fixed this by including the close link for both users who can close questions as well as users who can recommend closure. The fix will be in the next build, which probably won't go out until tomorrow.

Comment: Just confirmed that it is now rolled out and indeed fixed. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The suggested edit queue says

> #### Review the following answer

(or question, of course). That's not really correct; I'm not reviewing the *post*, I'm reviewing a suggested edit. The post type may be important enough to show, so how about something like

> #### Review the following suggested edit to an answer

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report! I've amended the language here so it goes "Review the following suggested _____ edit" <-- fill in the blank. Should be easier to understand, now. The fix will be in the following build, either this afternoon or tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Reviewing a suggested edit in a side-by-side mode is a nightmare. The two columns are too narrow:

[image]

But if I already have reviewed the posts or a consensus has been reached the width is fine:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Make better use of the screen real-estate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361376/289905).

Comment: (+1) With such thin columns when viewing on a 15" MacBook I now find myself scrolling/panning horizontally across code blocks a lot more to ascertain if/what suggested edits were made. Perhaps reducing the size of the outer (empty) page margin/padding and making the _"Actions"_ box thinner will enable the _"before"_ and _"after"_ columns to be wider. The _"Actions"_ box (in the third column) is currently the same width as the _"before"_ and _"after"_ columns - which just doesn't result in a good UX.

Comment: I've responded to this request elsewhere, but for now we're not going to address this particular request. I understand the concern but making this change would require a much larger set of changes that we're not prepared to make right now. We will potentially revisit it in the future.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Let's be consistent in terms of the numbering using a comma separator for thousands:

[image]

Comment: This was my bad! I fixed it, the fix will be out in the next build. Thanks for the report.

Comment: @kristinalustig: ...on second thought, that "Total" just below the badges is duplicated in the "All time" column. Is there anyplace else where one would see that "Total"? Otherwise it would seem kinda superfluous to have it duplicated so close to one another...

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Sometimes it is obvious what action should be taken in a review task (e.g. with spam, or rude/abusive posts).

It used to be more obvious that a review action couldn't be selected for the first few seconds after loading a review task - the options were buttons and the text was greyed out.

Now, there is a checkbox the text is not greyed out so the only visual cue to alert a user that the action is not yet available is the colour of the checkbox (which can be easy to miss).

Could something be done to make the fact that the options aren't available more obvious, e.g. grey the text out (though that may have dark mode readability implications), please?

**In light mode:**

[image: light]

**In dark mode:**

[image: dark]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  We actually have a class called `.is-deleted` which applies visual treatment to the label that we just weren't using.  I had to give the "No action needed/I'm done" pair some special treatment because "I'm done" has a lot of text that will spend a fair amount of time in the disabled state.

Answer (score 8):

### The author's name is no longer highlighted if they reviewed a suggested edit to one of their own posts

In the old UI for the suggested edits queue, if the author reviewed a suggested edit to one of their own posts, their name would appear in a blue highlight to make it clearer to others that the author reviewed the edit, especially if no one else reviewed or if their review contradicts the others (e.g. if they overrode an edit's outcome).

However, in the new UI, the author's name is no longer highlighted as it used to be:

[image: OP's name no longer highlighted]

I understand that the prior blue highlight (which matched the background for the author on user cards on questions as well as on comments they made) isn't feasible here as it's the same color as the background, so it will just mix in and not be visible.

However, please re-add in an indication (e.g. in text) that the author reviewed a suggested edit, as there used to be before.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Would it be possible in the suggested edit review queue to filter for tag-wiki edits?

Comment: Related feature-request: [How to follow / get a notification from tag wikis edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383057/289691) h/t to bad_coder that shared this answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 7):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

### Low Quality Posts queue

#### reviewing an answer

- The prominently displayed information is completely irrelevant to the task at hand as it is about the question only - hence
  [image: Post information]
- I cannot see the answer and the question at the same time any more
- about the *link* to the original post

  - before: the one one the right side (where now the submission window is displayed) would immediately open in a **new tab**, thus keeping my review open.
  - now: as @Glorfindel found out: clicking on the **question title** opens the **answer** which is somewhat unintuitive ;-)) **and** I have to take extra measures to open the link in a new tab.

Comment: The link to the answer is there, but it's highly confusing: just click on the title of the *question*.

Comment: @Glorfindel thx for the finding - I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I agree that it should be possible to see the question and the answer at the same time (without needing to open the question in a new window/tab).

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now that the review queues have been rolled out to international sites, an alignment issue has become apparent caused by singular/plural differences. This is Stack Overflow en español:

[image]

Please disregard the missing translations for the queue names. The queue with one item (Late Answers) is shifted to the left w.r.t. the other queues, and the number of items isn't horizontally centered with the word below it.

This issue does not appear on English sites, presumably because the words 'post' and 'posts' are much shorter than 'publicación' and 'publicaciónes'.

[image]

Comment: Good catch! I fixed this so it'll work regardless of how long the word for "posts" is. I also put my local environment in Spanish by default so I can catch this stuff earlier. Thanks for the report. The fix will be rolled out a bit later today!

Answer (score 7):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

### From the standpoint of a contributor who may have recently earned reviewing privileges…

the text, divorced as it is from the title, appears to be an answer.

**First impression**: for a split moment while  I was reviewing, I thought the question consisted of a single line. This is not strange considering that short posts usually end up in the review heap. Of course, if one reads the text it becomes clear that is not the case but my concern is about the first impression.

If I can make a suggestion, the title and body should *not* be separated by a line break or a row of buttons because it's easy to overlook the delicate grey button that tells the user which page they are *actually* looking at.

> [image: screenshot of EL&U review]

Just saying. Don't shoot the messenger.

I think this layout could create confusion on the smaller sites for old and new contributors alike.  For example,

> Have the review queues changed or [have I messed up my settings somehow](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/whats-with-the-review-queues)?

Comment: Related: [this report by Gino Mempin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360310/289905).

Comment: It’s also really strange to see the last editor where the author of the post is normally, instead of next to the author. It still makes me have to look twice and I’ve been using these queues for a while. I don’t understand why everything except the last editor was moved up.

Comment: @ColleenV That’s covered by [this report by Meta Andrew T.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360208/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yep, I’ve already upvoted that one.

Comment: @SebastianSimon the latter (by Andrew T)  I had seen before posting mine but, sorry, the issue discussed in the post by Gino wasn't clear. I thought it was dealing with something else. Now on more careful inspection, I see why my post is related.

Comment: Yeah, I’m just trying to link similar reports together, but the design has been criticized in multiple places and it’s all a very similar story: the design is just messy.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The site logo and the link at the bottom link to the homepage of the site. The logo links to `/questions`; this feels weird, especially since the breadcrumb seems to suggest `/review` is a subpage of `/questions`.

[image]

Comment: In response to other feedback, we've gone ahead and removed the breadcrumbs from this page entirely. The change will be out in the next build, today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

When choosing 'Edit and Reopen' in the Reopen Votes review queue, I get a non-responsive version of the edit page:

[image]

Comment: Oh my, you weren't kidding. That's so non-responsive it's almost kind of funny. Thanks for the heads up (and thanks for all your bug reports in this thread!)

Comment: You're welcome, thanks in advance for fixing them :)

Comment: @Glorfindel this just happens for you when you go to low width on the edit screen? I can't repro

Comment: @YaakovEllis I couldn't repro anymore either (and I just blew the only testcase), but perhaps it depends on the exact width of the browser? Judging from the screenshot, it's 638 pixels.

Comment: It is responsive for me all the way down to 200px. Marking as no-repro, if you can repro and give me steps, let me know.

Comment: @YaakovEllis [tag:status-completed-by-accident]?

Comment: @YaakovEllis [probably related bugreport](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3762/11900)

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

"Side-by-side Markdown" mode doesn't work for deleted posts (probably because I am <10k?). “Inlined“ and “Side-by-side“ work correctly See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/76876) review, for example:

[image]

and it keeps loading forever... The request made to `/revisions/.../diff?difftype=SideBySideMarkdown&begin=date&end=date` fails with a 404 error.

Comment: For me, it requested `https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/91910/diff?difftype=SideBySideMarkdown&begin=1611729826&end=1611940873&_=1611940873430` and returned HTTP 200 with  ["No changes to display"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CFIC.png) and link to [this full revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/91910/revisions) (yeah, that's the link to the duplicate instead) internally, but not shown on the review page.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  Previous reviewers are granted special permission to see deleted content that they've reviewed and we weren't applying those same rules to the revisions.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I don't have review queue privileges on any site other than Stack Overflow, so the only testing of this new system I have been able to do is on Meta.SO.

However, in the "Close Votes" reviews, I have noticed that there is no longer a "link" 'button' presented to the reviewers, with which to open the post in a new tab/window. (The post's title is still a link, but that opens in the same window.) Is this button also gone from the other queues?

Viewing a post in its 'natural environment' is sometimes very useful – especially for the "Late Answers" queue, where I often use that new tab to compare the post under review with existing answers, as a check for copy/pasting or other forms of plagiarism.

It seems to me that it would be very easy (if not trivial) to add this link back, probably in the right-hand portion of the display, where the "Admin" and "Developer" options are shown (for those who have access to such tools).

So, can we have the link link back, please?

Comment: Simply middle-click or `Ctrl` + left-click the link to open in a new tab.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks. I use a touchpad mostly, so middle-clicking (though possible) isn't that convenient. I just got used to the "link" button and felt that its absence was possibly an oversight.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Some people are doing reviews on mobile phones. yeah still possible, but even more inconvenient. UIs should provide the functionality that the user using the UIs need.

Comment: I've updated the link in so that the question title opens in a new tab instead of in the same tab. That fix will be in the next build, out today or tomorrow. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @kristinalustig Thanks very much. That change makes a big difference to my review process.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [support](/questions/tagged/support) [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers) [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

When a post is deleted through spam or R/A flags by the Community user, the content is masked, as demonstrated by this post:

[image]

But in the review queues, the mask is gone, and it shows the actual content:

[image]

Which *may* be problematic for R/A posts.  Is this the intended behavior, or a bug?

Comment: This is existing behavior and will be somewhat of a hassle to implement for all the different queues.  It's arguable that maybe we should show the post content because we're in a review context, like how it's still available in "revisions". It also doesn't have a big negative impact because it's only visible to high rep users and (I believe) users who performed the review.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [support](/questions/tagged/support) [vote-count](/questions/tagged/vote-count) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm unable to view the vote totals on a post in the Close/Reopen Votes queues.  This seems new, as it was just fine before; can we fix it?  Or is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Do you mean what choices previous reviewers have taken on that review task, or the upvotes/downvotes on a post?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Upvotes/downvotes.

Comment: It was me, I broke this.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

One of the action descriptions in the Suggested Edits queue is grammatically wrong:

> This edit clearly improve the post.

[image]

That must be *improves*.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the Suggested Edits queue, the 'Proposed x hours ago' and 'Follow' are so alike, that it doesn't really stand out that 'Follow' is a (clickable) action.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It's possible to send the wrong action in the First Posts review queue, as follows:

1. Select the No Action Needed radio button.
2. Do something, like voting, that would trigger the I'm Done radio button. The No Action Needed radio button is now selected but disabled.
3. Click Submit. The review action is now 'No Action Needed' but doesn't correspond with your actual actions on the post.

[image]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  Performing an action will actually select "I'm done", while undoing all actions will deselect it.  I expect there to be more discussion around this on other answers, but this satisfies this specific bug so I'm closing it out.

Answer (score 6):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Review Progress

Now, while you are reviewing a post, you can not see your *overall progress* in a particular review type (Late Answers, First posts, etc.), only the *daily progress*.

If you click the Stats button, yes you can see the overall progress, but then you also lose the post that you were just reviewing.

Why not show both daily and overall progress together?

Why has the overall progress bar been removed?

Comment: Especially on smaller sites the overall progress indicator can be more useful than the daily progress indicator, because 1. the queues are often so empty that you cannot hit the daily limit even if you wanted to and 2. because of the empty queues it takes a very long time to get badges and it's nice to see the progress (as opposed to bigger sites, i.e., SO, where many regular reviewers already have badges and there are many review items each day so the daily limit is more interesting than the badge progress).

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Can the text of the Submit button be changed to better reflect what it does in cases where further steps are required, for example when rejecting an edit.

[image]

The submission of a review should mean "here is my completed review", but instead in these cases it means "I'd like to go to the next step of the current review". As a result having the button labelled "Submit" when there are further actions to take is confusing. Even after reviewing near enough 7k suggested edits I still found myself doubting if the action was correct.

It would make more sense for the button to be labelled "Continue". This works for single actions, like approval, as it indicates "Yes, I'm done, I'm ready to continue reviewing". And for reviews with multiple actions, like rejection, it indicates "Yes, I'm ready for the next step of the review".

---

Ideally I would like to see that when you click the Reject button (or Close button or whatever button is relevant for the current review), the reason dialog then appears where you can select an option (without submitting it).

Once selected the review form would be updated to say, "Reject: clearly conflicts with author's intent" or whichever action was chosen, at which point you could review your review before clicking Submit to finish the review (at which point the actual close vote etc. would be made).

In this case clicking Submit would make sense as you *are* submitting a final response for the review, rather than being part way through the process.

Comment: This is really good feedback. We're not totally sure what to do with it yet but are considering "Continue" instead of "Submit" as an option. I'll leave this under review for now but we are definitely still thinking about it!

Answer (score 6):

When reviewing a suggested edit on an answer, I wanted to see the answer on its own. I looked for a link to the answer, but couldn't find it. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It turns out that the presentation of the question at the top (with the votes, author, date and other information about the question) actually links to the answer. I can certainly see how it's useful, but 1. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) it's unintuitive to look for a link to the answer there and 2. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) it's misleading to have all the metadata of the question on a link to the answer.

There's a way to see the answer on its own inline, which is to select the “Side-by-side” view. That's not completely obvious, and I think it isn't accurate when there are diffs that overlap fancy formatting features such as MathJax (I haven't checked recently, maybe that's resolved now?).

Answer (score 5):

Has there been any thought given to how changing the number of steward badges awarded will impact the relative value of badges?

With the current rules users can easily have more gold badges than bronze badges. It also creates a discrepancy with the remaining badges, like Copy-Editor, Marshall, etc; while devaluing the relative overall weight of tag badges...

Other gold badges that could be awarded multiple times were extremely hard to get (while reviewing in queues like FP seems potentially trivial by comparison.)

This choice seems to go a long way in promoting reviewing. But at the cost, in a gamification sense, of unbalancing a long standing status-quo. (Looking at gaming reviews this could be considered a risky choice.)

The title of this thread *"Visual design changes"* doesn't fully capture a *"game changing"* alteration to overall badge rules.

Comment: As a dedicated reviewer who spends at least two or more hours reviewing posts out of a sense of duty to maintaining site quality, I welcome this this change.  While some users on math.se never review but spend all their time answering questions and getting a new gold or silver here are there, my dozens of thousands of reviews have gone unnoticed.  I'm not looking to game reviews; I simply seek fitting recognition of contributions to the site already afforded those who only answer posts.

Comment: I don't think this diminishes the value of a gold badge - assuming that they have any particular value. The reality is that the total number of people with this badge remains unchanged while we recognize and appreciate the efforts of people who don't just stop reviewing at 1k reviews. There's someone on SO with 100k and I think that having 100 gold badges for that monumental effort as a more visible indicator of participation than the somewhat hidden top reviewers page is fair and worthy of recognition. We do much to endlessly recognize posting but little to recognize curation.

Comment: @amWhy I just noticed, the possible change to the steward badge was announced [*"Improving Review Queues - Design overview II: Changing review bans and other new features"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346903) but no one mentioned it in the answers. There wasn't any wider discussion on this specific change.

Comment: You make a good point about parity with other badges for curation actions and I'd love to have a discussion of other badges that may benefit from being repeatable rather than one-time. I invite you to start a separate discussion or FR here on MSE to consider where else we can further recognize these valuable efforts by our community. No promises but I'd love to see the discussion.

Comment: @Catija I will post an FR today here on MSE, I don't mean to sound *"argumentative"* (I was considering what the right way write this post should be). I'll try to make a good post.

Comment: "...while reviewing in queues like FP seems potentially trivial by comparison..." Doing 1000 reviews is still a lot of work, if you are not robo-reviewing. Doing it multiple times even more. There is rep and there are badges of different colors. I never really understood the conversion rates between all of them. I can only say that I tend to be more aware of the rep that users have than of the number and distribution of badges.

Comment: @Catija About *There's someone on SO with 100k and I think that having 100 gold badges for that monumental effort as a more visible indicator of participation than the somewhat hidden top reviewers page is fair and worthy of recognition* and *You make a good point about parity with other badges for curation actions* I suspect there are people on SO with an insane amount of flags too and I would also say it is only fair for them to be awarded the same way with multiple Marshal badges.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Could we have the "Tools" and "Meta reviews" buttons back on the /review page? On the old page in the top right corner was a "Tools" button that took you to /tools. At the bottom of the page under the normal reviews was also a similar button to take you to meta/review. Could these buttons be added back in? And preferably could they both be added into the top right, there's enough space there and it means the "Meta reviews" button won't look odd and lost at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This seems to have been [tag:status-completed]: the "Tools" button is on the top right corner (shown only if you have enough rep to access), and there's a link to meta review queues on the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Overall, these changes look very nice, indeed! However, like many others, I haven't been able to test them, in fury … the only active site on which I have review privileges is Meta SO, and the queues there have been empty since this announcement.

My main concern (also expressed in Shog9's penultimate paragraph) is this:

> There is more incentive to continue reviewing. The Steward badge can
> now be earned multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in each queue. If
> you have already completed 2,000 or more reviews, we will backfill any
> additional Steward badges that you have already earned. You can expect
> to see them accrue over the next few days.

While I have no problem with the *concept* of rewarding and/or incentivising reviewers, the prospect of such 'easy' gold badges<sup>1</sup> may simply attract more "robo-reviewers".

Would it be better (or even possible), perhaps, to have somewhat steeper criteria for awarding additional Steward badges. For example, at 2,000 reviews, then 4,000, then 8,000, *etcetera*. Or only at every 5K or 10K reviews? Users reaching 10K review milestones are relatively rare events<sup>2</sup>, and the award could be offered *conditionally*, subject to approval by moderators or staff (or some other select group); that way, obvious robo-reviewers – who, ultimately, make *more* work for the 'good' (i.e. experienced and conscientious) curators – would not be seen to benefit from their gamification of the review process.

Nevertheless, my aforementioned concerns notwithstanding, I have to admit to looking forward to the *circa* 45 extra gold badges I'm likely to be awarded between now and the end of February.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, on Stack Overflow, there are often 3 or 4 review queues for which the daily quota for reviewers is 40: Three or four more Gold Badges every 25 days!

<sup>2</sup> A quick look at SO's [Close Vote Review Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) suggests around 150 such "10K" events in the entire history of the site. Once that backlog were cleared, the occurrence of new events would probably be sufficiently infrequent so as to not overload the 'approval committee'.

Comment: FWIW, the original rationale for capping the badge at 1K was that at some point [extrinsic motivation fails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation) - if the work isn't intrinsically rewarding, folks should be encouraged to STOP DOING IT. Review shouldn't need a static group grinding away every day; like the site itself, it should have a constant influx of new people and a core group of folks providing oversight and guidance. My personal preference would be to encourage folks like the SOCVR and facilitate their interactions with review.

Comment: Maybe there should be somethink like the Steward badge for doing lots of reviews in the same tag.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When performing a Close votes review task on a narrow screen, the suggested duplicate(s) are truncated, e.g. in [this Meta Stack Overflow task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/28105), where the full title of question that the task relates to is shown on multiple lines whereas the duplicate target is truncated to fit in one line:

> [image]

Here the full title of the target is "[*If you do something on keyup, make sure you got the associated keydown first*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387220/1364007)".

Given that (I am assuming) the duplicate targets are shown in the review task in part to save the reviewer from having to click on the link to view the question, it'd be nice to save the reviewer from having to click on the link to view the full title of the question.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the [main Review Queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) webpage there are "History" links.

If we choose the [History for **Reopen** Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history) there is an "Action" column, choosing [one of the prior **Reopen** reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/76973) presents a screen such as this; showing **no** Next button, nor proclaiming that all available reviews have been completed:

> [image: Reopen Votes Queue]

If we choose the [History for **Close** Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) there is an "Action" column, choosing [one of the prior **Close** reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/76967) presents a screen such as this; showing ***either*** a Next button, ...

> [image: Close Votes Queue - With Next Button]

... or explaining that all available reviews have been completed. To see this image [click here, keep clicking next](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close) until it appears:

> [image: Close Votes Queue - With 'Completed Message']

The Reopen Queue is missing its "Next" button and, at completion of available reviews, its 'reviews completed message'. Note that there is another [feedback explaining that the "Next" button should be a single action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360217/282094); I agree with that, I'm just reporting the inconsistency in the **current** implementation.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed a few minutes ago, I'll leave adding the red tag to the feedback to the person who made the fix. [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAE2y.jpg). Thanks for the rapid repair.

Answer (score 5):

Request for "Review | Close votes".

Please add the possibility to also, directly vote on the corresponding question from that UI.

**Rationale**: it takes 3 downvotes to enable delete voting. Every person who does review close votes should be able to *easily* work towards that.

Yes, that simple. I often see bad questions that also deserve a downvote, but then I need to explicitly open that question in another browser tab to get to that. And far too often, the result is a bad question that was closed, and that deserves to be deleted (which the lazy OP don't do, they just walk away to not care about the garbage). And I would delete vote it right there, but too bad, other "close reviews" came without a downvote. So: stuck.

Other review queues include the "in place voting", so please add it this queue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  We already added this feature to the new queues as shown in the screenshots in the question.  Is there somewhere we missed?

Comment: @BrianNickel I might have overlooked that. I was under the impression that the SO pages would already show that. But if that is already there, or will be coming: perfect:

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When hovering over the avatars for the "Recent reviewers" in the [/review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) page a review stats card appears showing a summary of the user's review stats:

> [image]

Currently this only appears for the six users who have most recently performed reviews in a given queue. Could this expanded information appear when hovering over avatars in other places, e.g. in the [stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) pages?

> [image]

I'm aware it's possible to view this manually by using a '[hidden feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214527/284827)', (e.g. [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)'s close vote information on Meta Stack Exchange is at https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/user-info/2/295232), but this is undocumented (and a faff).

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization)

Translation for "Total: $count$" was lost (e.g. on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats)):

> [image: Unable to translate]

[Recently added translation](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Total%3A) is not used now.

This issue is probably related to [that feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361344/339911) .

Comment: It's now available, but untranslated at 66c4c5112f455a19afde47829df363fa

Comment: @BrianNickel why is the count variable excluded from the sentence?

Comment: Oof, that's a fair point.  I had thought it was because of pluralization, but it looks like the old localization was accepting a number.  So probably a minor accident that wasn't caught in review.  I'll see about squeezing this into another PR.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

I see no reason why there’s new line inside [Low Quality Posts queue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) name. There’s enough place for text to be on the same row (look at the above row with queue description).

> [image: ruSO]

Screenshot from ruSO, but other non-English sites (with long enough text) are also affected.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Same user listed twice on [audit review](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/582173):

> [image: same user listed twice]

Comment: That's because they did review it twice, somehow.  Maybe the event got bound twice or there's something unexpected in the code?  This is an extremely rare event, having happened 5 times in total on ruSO and 5 times last year on SO.  Since it looks fairly benign and very uncommon, I'm inclined to do nothing for now.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On my iPhone 11 with iOS 14, if you scroll all the way down to the footer and then choose 'Close', the close dialog hides under the 'review action widget' and there's no way for you to reach the 'Close' button you need to complete the review.

[image]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  Legacy popups have a default z-index of 2000, which is pretty low in our new design system.  I've given these two popups a z-index of 9000 to bring them in line with other ones.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [review](/questions/tagged/review) [close-dialog](/questions/tagged/close-dialog) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When reviewing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/76986) item in the Close Votes Queue, I switched to the "Answers" tab on the Review Task, and tried submitting a close vote in the new Actions menu.  But, like in the old queue, the button [didn’t bring up the close dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/256282).  Clicking “Edit” and submitting that on both the “Duplicate” and “Answers” tabs still brings you to the edit page of the actual review task, so the lost QuestionID appears to apply only to the close action.

[image: Nothing happens when clicking on "Submit" when "Close" selected, on Answers and Duplicate tabs]

This had [previously been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/256282) with the old review UI, but the new UI also introduces the "Answers" tab, and the bug has also been introduced there. (Also, making sure that that bug isn't forgotten since the screenshots show the old UI.)

Comment: This has been fixed in a roundabout way, with a design change that hides the review UI when off the question tab.  What's happening is that the close dialog is hosted inside a div inside the post menu, so clicking "Close" would attempt to show it inside an element that's already invisible.

Comment: @BrianNickel This used to work correctly in the old review UI a long time ago. However, it stopped working with it fairly recently, and that same issue got carried forward to the new UI. Why not fix it for the new UI? Does the nature of the new UI mean that you can't go back to how it used to work properly with the old UI?

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

> Actions menu - We’ve removed the actions buttons for a menu-style component.

When choosing to close vote having 2 actions -choose close and click submit, before getting to the close reasons menu- is just much less productive and inconvenient.

> Selecting an action now requires a bit of pause and mitigates robo-reviewer behaviors we've seen in the past.

Perhaps the 3K queues could dispense the 2 step action, I feel frustrated by having to click 2 actions to get to the close reasons, image the frustration of reviewers who do 40-80 reviews per day.

An argument can be made that this will only impact vanilla users, reviewers who use userscripts will circumvent the double action.

> mitigates robo-reviewer behaviors

From my recent experience in the 3k queues I've mostly seen what I think are experienced reviewers I just can't imagine them fitting the profile of a robot-reviewer.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer if the menu shows up as soon as you check the radio button. Example: **1:** Click radio button. **2:** Close reasons pop up. Pick the one you want. **4:** Click the submit button on the close reasons dialog. Selected close reason appears as small text underneath the "Close" radio button which is now selected. **5:** Click Submit underneath the radio buttons to lock that in and move to next item.

Comment: Same for "Recommend Deletion" in VLQ, "Reject" in Suggested Edits, and I would go so far to remove the menu entirely from "Reopen" in Reopen Votes, because the action of checking the radio and clicking Submit is already a two step process which will hopefully mitigate most misclicks.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please change the text of the button:

[image]

To "Meta review queue*s*", as a Meta has more than just one (that's one button for all the queues, not one for each queue).

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Dialog for leaving a comment when reviewing to delete an answer in the low quality queue is not responsive

When I review an item in the low quality queue as "Delete" or "Recommend Deletion", the dialog box to select a comment is not responsive, and requires horizontal scrolling to view completely:

[image: Non-responsive comment dialog which requires scrolling on a mobile device]

I'm able to scroll to the right to find the button to submit the review, but I'm unable to scroll to the left to see the full content of each comment option.

Can this dialog please be made responsive, just like the close reason dialog?

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  I just completely missed that this dialog existed.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### When reviewing first posts (and in other review queues) - New Contributor has been lost

The information that a user is a new contributor has been lost on the main first post review page. Previously, the question was shown with the avatar in the usual place with New Contributor "tag" shown below it. Now, with the avatar being much smaller and at the top (above the question), the New Contributor tag has been lost.

Points to note:

- Admittedly, if it is the First Post review queue, then the user most probably is a *New Contributor*.
- However, as we were emphatically told a year or two ago (when the New Contributor indicator was introduced) to be more gentle/forgiving in our edits/comments/etc. towards common newbie posting mistakes, then that info should still be prominent... or does that advice no longer stand?
- Yes, you could right click the question title and open the question to see this information, but why add more clicks/work to see information that was once so immediately clear?

Comment: Also if you start adding a comment then the usual new contributor message is shown - which is arguably one of the more important situations where you need to be reminded to Be Nice. But I agree that it is inconvenient that you cannot see this when you start reviewing the post.

Answer (score 4):

Bit of an obscure curiosity, but couldn't resist asking...

I noticed that when there are multiple potential duplicates others have chosen in the close queue, those are now shown with letters ("Duplicate A", "Duplicate B", etc.) instead of with numbers as they were before ("Duplicate 1", "Duplicate 2", etc.)

However, I'm curious to know something: what if there are more than 26 potential duplicates others have chosen (which is possible through recommend closure flags)? How will the duplicates be lettered beyond the letter Z? Will they appear with a proper letter (e.g. "AA", "AB", etc.)?

[image]

Comment: So, I'm not exactly sure why the design is like this but I implemented it so I can tell you what'll happen.  The first thing to consider is that it's hard to get more duplicates than the number of close votes available (3 or 5).  I _guess_ you could with recommend close flags, but I'd have a tough time envisioning that.  You wouldn't be able to get more than 5 on the reopen queue because we don't let moderators add more than 5 originals to a reason.  So, I have "Duplicate A" -> "Duplicate E" in a switch statement.

Comment: _If_ there are more than 5, we just switch to numbers for all of them.  "Duplicate 1", "Duplicate 2", ...

Comment: @BrianNickel Why not just use numbers to begin with…? This is just asking for bug reports in the future, where “sometimes it’s letters and sometimes it’s numbers”.

Comment: I didn't create the design but I think that defaulting to letters makes sense - this is a number-rich row and putting "Duplicate 1" next to "Answers (1)" invites more confusion. Labeling them by letter instead of by number makes them clearly readable as labels instead of tallies.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the Close Votes review queue, for community-specific close reasons the number of close votes is shown (left). This is nice, but can we have the same for the general close reasons (Needs details or clarity etc.), just as the regular flag dialog (right)?

[image]

Comment: What about the "1 votes" part? :)

Comment: I have a giant S but I'm [afraid to use it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/295232).

Comment: I've added this in, and it should be in a bit later today. Good feedback, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

When a review queue is empty, clicking on the "return to ..." invariably returns to the active question queue.  If I had been looking at the "unanswered" queue, that setting is lost.  (Active on TeX - LaTeX.)

**addendum:**

On connecting to the site (https://tex.stackexchange.com/) I typically look around a bit before going to check the review queues.  I'm working on a Dell laptop running Ubuntu Linux, and connect via Firefox.  I haven't (as far as I'm aware) reset anything other than the size of the browser window, but that shouldn't make any difference.

The main window has a list of options in a column on the left; from the top: Home, Questions, Tags, Users, Unanswered.  Then the middle column with the question area, and a right-hand column with various notices and links.  Above the actual questions is a list of option boxes: Active, Bountied, ...  The Active queue is in effect when I first connect; I sometimes select Unanswered (from the list on the left) to see what's there.

But when I click on the icon to see the review queues, the page geometry changes.  The option list on the left has disappeared.  (It was there until the last design change for the review queues.)  I used to return to the main page by clicking on Questions, but that's no longer possible.  I believe that if I had been looking at Unanswered, that's what it would return to, but I can't prove that.  Now, when a queue has been cleared, this possibility is offered:

> Want to get back to the questions? Return to TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange.

where the text following "Return to" is a link.  Clicking on that link always returns to the Active queue, regardless of which queue option was in effect before loading the review queue page.

Comment: Thanks for the report! I'm digging into bugs right now - could you please provide a bit more information about what's happening here? I'm afraid that I don't fully understand the issue based on your description.

Comment: @kristinalustig -- I've described a typical session.  I hope that's what you were asking for.

Comment: The post is confusing and some screenshots would help. _“The option list on the left has disappeared”_ — if you mean the [left navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/289905), this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360502/289905); you can still access the menu using the hamburger icon. You keep talking about “active question queue” and “The Active queue”. If you mean [question lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNOC1.png), those aren’t _queues_ ([review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review/info) are “queues”).

Comment: And these aren’t called “option boxes”, they’re just navigation items. I was confused by the usage of the word “connecting”; perhaps “accessing” is a better choice. The [“Return to …” link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCV6y.png) indeed links to the _homepage_, i.e. `https://tex.stackexchange.com/`, but look at the small site logo in the breadcrumb navigation (referred to in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360216/289905), the one preceding “› Review queues”. It takes you to `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions`. These are different pages with different question lists.

Comment: The filter that you used last (“Active”, “Unanswered”, etc.) is probably remembered on `/questions`, not on `/`; there is no setting being lost. So is this post a [tag:feature-request] to change the “Return to …” link to `/questions`? By the way, [tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43sz2.png) can also be used on the [Questions (i.e. `/questions`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions) page, which have similar filters, as an alternative to the left navigation. I suspect they behave similarly in the context of this report.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information there. I understand now what is happening - that's not a change that's within the scope of this project, but if you want to open up broader discussion about how we handle those sorts of links and remembering tabs, you could spin off a separate meta post to gather thoughts from the community?

Comment: @kristinalustig -- Thanks for looking into this.  I have learned from another comment that the "hamburger" icon will restore the "left navigation" (I'm not entirely familiar with this jargon), and that provides the facility I'm looking for.  As for finding the "hamburger" icon, the contrast on my laptop screen is not optimum, and that icon tends to disappear into the background; I'll have to work on the screen tuning.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is no string to translate for “This edit clearly improves the post.” I can’t found it in traducir.win

Screenshot from Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: ruso]

Comment: The one sentence I do understand had to be wrong :|

Comment: @bad_coder which one?

Comment: The one in English off course :)

Comment: The key is:3Ab3c593bc8fd5f34621c3193aceb898e4

Comment: @gbianchi [doesn't exist](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english?q=key%3A3Ab3c593bc8fd5f34621c3193aceb898e4)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ try this one: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16063

Comment: sorry the key was for spanish translations ;)

Comment: @gbianchi thanx, translation added!

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Another issue with narrow screens (this time it's <s>personal</s> browser specific).

When shown a Low quality posts review task (and possibly other review task types) where the title for the post under review is long, there is no wrapping of the title text.

For instance, [this review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28413143) is for [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380663/1364007) to the question [PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPipes.php on line 140](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51610323/1364007).

On Chrome 88.0.4324.190 and Edge 85.0.564.67 (both on Windows 10), and Chrome 88.0.4324.181 on Android 10, the question title causes horizontal scroll but the answer body is fine:

[image]

On Firefox 85.0.2 on Windows 10, the title is wrapped - so there is no horizontal scroll bar:

[image]

Presumably wrapping (and therefore no scroll bar) is the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report - I made this fix; it will go out in the next build, likely a bit later today.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When doing edits to the already proposed edit or reject+edit in review queue on narrow display I face problem that I can't get to the beggining of the interface, I can get only to the end. Screen attached - not able to move further to the left.

[image: the problem image]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  I've learned in the past 2 months how wildly aggressive `<pre>` tags are about displaying at full width.  I had even applied code here that resolved the issue at a couple responsive breakpoints, but we changed flex direction on narrow devices and the `min-width: 0%` approach stopped working.  Adding `max-width: 100%` was the other piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Some completed review tasks (this is definitely the case for the Low quality posts queue) do not show the action that I chose until the review task is complete (i.e. the reviewers of the item reach a consensus).

For instance, I reviewed [this review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28450103) but I don't see what action I took (and it doesn't show that I have reviewed it at all) on the review page itself:

[image]

but in my [history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) (and the review-generated comment that I posted on the answer being reviewed) clearly show that I have reviewed it:

[image]

Completed Low quality posts review items correctly show the action I took, e.g.

[image]

---

This does not seem to be the behaviour in other queues, e.g. Close votes or Suggested edits:

[image]

[image]

---

This appears to be due to me having reached the daily limit of reviews in this queue although I think I've seen this happen when I still have available reviews for the day. For the same review task:

Before reaching the daily limit:

[image]

After reaching the daily limit:

[image]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  I had moved the permission check higher in the code and _thought_ I had accounted for all the cases that had preceded it.  I missed this one.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

No source string (in transifex/traducir) to translate for:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

> [image]

[Link to review](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/580934)

Comment: Already reported:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361714/edit-rejection-string-edit-does-not-improve-the-quality-of-the-post-needs-to-b

Comment: This has made it into Traducir as 258396b5baf8f6192c74f66e93229a7b.  It's fairly unlikely that a string will not get marked for translation, this bug mostly speaks to our rough translation pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I got a question in the Low Quality Posts which has a bounty in the grace period. My decision on that review was to close the question, but after choosing the close option I got a banner on the top of the page that said: “Unable to close a question with an active bounty”.

> [image]

<sub>Sorry for the screenshot from a non-English site, but I only have that one.</sub>

My suggestion is that something needs to be improved on the review pages. For instance, remove the bountied question from the review entirely, or grey out options that are not actually available for the item under review.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

This is the responsive view of the review stats when used on a mobile device.
I encircled (yes freehand) all instances where usernames are randomly clipped to the next row due to a fixed width. In this case it happens to exactly half of the usernames. While some users have really long names, a name like [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) with its 10 characters isn't one of those. It would be good to see them on just one line. In the case there is a higher number of reviewed items (for example more then 1K) the name gets clipped to:

Glorfin
del

Which IMHO is even more awkward.

I appreciate the effort the designers made to use as much screen real-estate as possible in potential, by putting the daily and all time lists next to each other. But the screens might simply be too narrow in these cases, and it would look better if they are stacked upon each other.

[image: Screenshot of the review stats page (Thanks to Wai Ha Lee for combining the images into one)] (click to enlarge)

Answer (score 4):

**Feature request: Display the author of the answer when reviewing a suggested edit on an answer.**

While reviewing a suggested edit I realized that I had to navigate to the answer to see who had authored it. There are a couple of "suggested edit" situations where it is important to know who asked the question, who wrote the answer, and who is proposing the edit.

The most common situation on ELL is that we have a migrated question from a new user who then creates a new account with the same name as the account that asked the migrated question and they are really confused about how things work. They can't edit their question and they can't comment on answers to their question, so they try suggested edits and writing comments as answers. If it's apparent in the review queues that this is what's going on, we can help them get on track more quickly.

The second situation is when someone is attempting to incorporate information from comments made by the author of a post—it is important to know that the comment was made by the author and not someone else when judging whether it is appropriate for it to be incorporated into the answer.

I apologize if I missed an existing answer that already covers this; I searched all the answers for "suggested edit" but I was just skimming so I may have missed one.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Will this bug be fixed?

[In the close vote review queue, when you switch to look at a duplicate question, the close button is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/256282)

(I haven't been able to test it because the queue here on MSE is always empty.)

Comment: Yes, it's broken in the new queue.  I haven't dared to test the Reopen action, though ;)  Yet.

Comment: I mentioned on [this duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360519/235711) that we're now hiding the actions when you're not looking at the question itself.  So it's fixed but in a different way.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be tagged status-completed? Fixing a bug by removing the functionality altogether is not really a fix, that's like "I have a flat tire on my car and I fixed it by removing the wheel so now my car doesn't have a flat tire anymore". A real fix would be to make sure the Close button works when a duplicate is in view. The [reply by Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361178/) on the old bug report (2 days after the above comment) seems to suggest that this is planned, so maybe change the status here as well?

Comment: @BrianNickel I saw this still broken in one of the MSE queues yesterday, have to switch back from the duplicate to the first tab to get the button to press.

Comment: @BrianNickel Status not completed. -  Example: [Choices Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R138Z.png), [No Choices - Dupe A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coq9e.png) or [No Choices - Dupe B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLS2n.png).

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Found a couple of problems in the Late Answers queue on AU.  [This](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1123630) review, for example:  First, when I click the edit button on an **answer**, it shows this:

[image]

*Answer*, not question.  The view count is also largely irrelevant, as the number is never shown for an answer; it was also *answered*, not asked, on that day.  Perhaps we could remove those?

Comment: The Suggested Edits queue has this problem too if you choose Improve Edit.

Answer (score 3):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

In the First Posts review queue, when I go to edit the tags on a question, the [How to Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZehQ.png) list pops up.  This is normal behavior, but once I click in the input field, or start typing a tag, the list disappears instead of switching to the [How to Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKaIr.png) help list.  Is this normal, or a bug?

Tested with [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1123583) task.

Comment: This is existing behavior that got carried over into the new design.  I'll review and see if we can bring the other instructions over.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It feels a bit stupid to have to *select* 'I'm Done' or 'No Action Needed' in the First Posts / Late Answers review queues. There's always only one option enabled; can it be selected by default please? Or is this a deliberate choice to prevent robo-reviewing? In that case, I'll probably write a userscript to do it ...

Comment: Keep in mind that the whole point of the "No Action Needed" button back when it was implemented was to stop robo-reviewers from simply upvoting everything instead: it was one click while upvoting and clicking "I'm Done" was two. Initially, I was thinking that one could make "No Action Needed" require the usual two clicks, but make "I'm Done" only require one, but that would remove that difference.

Comment: Fair enough, if it's a deliberate choice then I won't press the matter (but I'll still write that userscript).

Comment: I totally agree with the sentiment of this answer, well said. Although I would have omitted "a bit".

Comment: The UX here is definitely a challenge, the two possible outcomes dependent on other actions definitely pushes the limits of this design pattern.  I'll bring this up to design, but in the mean time I've made it so performing an action selects "I'm Done".  In that way, both scenarios require two clicks.  (e.g., upvote + submit versus "No action needed + submit).  I'm going to mark this as complete and use https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361030/235711 for tracking.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

I'm not sure if the new review queues support migration, or if this is just a coincidence. I just reviewed [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/review/close/1034223) and the dialog showed four people voted to migrate it to Stack Overflow. I did as well, but the question is still there, and it has peculiar 'locked'/'unlocked' events in its [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/1621270/timeline).

[image]

Comment: Something weird happened but I can't find any logs for it.  There weren't any exceptions reported by either the closure route or the private migration API.  The timeline makes it clear that it attempted something and that it failed, but beyond that it's a mystery.  I was able to migrate successfully on my local instance, so I'm going to say this is probably unrelated to the review queues.

Comment: I think this is because the migration was blocked, as the author was banned or rate-limited from posting on Stack Overflow. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261324/why-is-the-community-user-having-another-battle-with-the-moderators

Comment: @Sonic that could very well be the case (especially if the author has any deleted posts on SO). An event in the timeline 'migration failed because of a question block' would really help to clarify things, but I understand if the company wants to keep that information private.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah, I'd make the timeline event a lot clearer for blocked migrations in general rather than what it is now. But it is easy to check for the [other reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) that can block a migration, and if none of those apply, it's that case.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It's not possible to flag questions for closure in the Low Quality Posts review queue on sites where you have between 2k and 3k reputation. When I select 'Recommend close' and click 'Submit', no close dialog appears:

[image]

There's no network call performed after clicking submit (that's probably the problem); I don't see any JavaScript errors in the console. On sites where I do have the necessary 3k reputation to vote to close, the close dialog shows as normal.

Comment: This is already reported https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361336/344828 and in a couple other places - should have a fix out soon. Thanks!

Comment: That's a different queue (but probably the same bug, but I have no way to tell :)) and since this one is reputation-dependent, I thought it was worthwhile to mention.

Comment: Hah, yes, I think it's the same bug, and also reputation-dependent. Basically, the recommend close action tries to reference a link via javascript that doesn't exist if you don't have close permissions.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Follow-up on [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361016/295232): the "action detection logic" in the First Posts queue does not react to retracting a flag.

1. Open a First Posts review queue item
2. Flag the post – this will select the "I'm Done" option and enable the "Submit" button
3. Retract the flag
4. This *should* reset the state (deselect the "I'm Done" option and disable the "Submit" button), but it doesn't; I'm still able to complete the item as "I'm Done".

Comment: Potential exploit.

Comment: After looking at this more thoroughly, this is an edge case that would require extensive backend changes, so we're going to status-decline this particular issue for now. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When more than 3 tags entered in filter box the popup notification from the top of the page contains an extra border around the text:

> [image]

Comment: That’s a notification inside a notification!

Comment: @SebastianSimon and we need to go deeper! Good example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329360/339911).

Comment: I fixed this! We had a notice inside a notice. I un-Inception-ed it, the fix will be out a bit later today. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 2):

> [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
>
> The left sidebar links are available in the top-bar "hamburger" menu (far left). This is consistent on all of the new review pages

I am not sure whether this is a bug or intentional, but when going to the *all queues* page, the left navigation pane is non-existent. This is how it looks in the new UI over at Meta Stack Overflow:

[image]

And this is how it looks in the current UI over at Stack Overflow:

[image]

Comment: @Yaakov is this part of a wider design change of the site? It might be consistent between review pages of the different sites, but it's inconsistent between the review page and the rest of the site...

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When not logged in, the questions in Close Votes review tasks are greyed/faded out, e.g.

- [This incomplete review on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/28129):

  > [image]
- [This completed review on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/28075):

  > [image]

---

This isn't how it currently is, e.g.

- [This incomplete review on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/28233810):

  > [image]
- [This completed review on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/28205856):

  > [image]

---

Could this be fixed/reverted please? I can't think of a reason why this would be a deliberate choice, but in case it it I've added the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag.

Comment: That section literally has `style="opacity: 0.30000000000000004;"` on it — no semantic class name, no explanation.

Comment: During loading, we use jQuery's fade function to dim the view, which is a carryover from the original code.  There was a JavaScript error that prevented us from unfading for logged out users.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

(this could be a side-effect of [this other bug report about questions being faded out when not logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360505/284827))

When not logged in, clicking on the "show [x] more comments" at the bottom of questions (e.g. in [the this review on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/28129)) does nothing:

> [image]

Comment: The console says `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.state.reviewTaskId')`.

Comment: This was related to the faded review bug.  A JavaScript error occurred early on in the code and everything after it failed.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

If a question has already been closed since you opened the review, selecting "Close" and clicking "Submit" has no visible effect.  In the current version, you get an error message informing you that the question is already closed.

Behind the scenes, there's a 500 error on a request to `GET https://[site]/flags/questions/[post-id]/close/popup`.

Comment: This fix is building out.  We were sending error messages to a non-existent view.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I'm not sure if this is intentional, and what will happen on February 16th, but the order of the 'I'm Done' and 'No Action Needed' buttons has been reversed:

[image]

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or a deliberate choice? Right now, it messes up my muscle memory a bit :)

Comment: This change accidentally bled through.  "I'm done" is above "Not action needed" in the new design and the reversed order carried over here.  Given that it's been this way for a week and that it only has one week left, I'm inclined to leave things as they are.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[This suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1038332) is proposed by a user whose avatar isn't working. That looks rather awkward in Firefox on macOS:

[image]

Safari (left) and Chrome (right) handle it better:

[image] [image]

Comment: This is fixed.  The alt-text was so we wouldn't have an unlabeled link, but the link is just there to increase the mouse hit area, so the solution was to omit the avatar link from screen readers and keyboard navigation with `tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"` in addition to `alt=""`, which will hopefully be a better overall experience for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

#### When reviewing first posts (in the case of an answer):

**Radio Buttons**
There are two issues with the buttons:

1. Pointless clicks
2. Standard radio button UX is not followed

*Pointless clicks*

Pointless clicks are required. Once an edit has been done, there is only one radio button available ("I'm done" - the other is greyed out), which **must** be clicked before being able to click "submit".

Utterly pointless! If only one option is available (in a radio button group) then it should be automatically selected. Otherwise a checkbox should be used<sup>1</sup>.

*Radio button UX*

When first opening, the "I'm Done" is disabled... so surely that should mean that "No action is needed", as it is the only enabled option, should be selected by default?

But no, if you action something (i.e. make a change to the post, vote, etc.) then "No action is needed" becomes disabled, yet "I'm done" (which magically becomes enabled) is not selected by default.

This is *not* how radio buttons work. The radio buttons are extremely confusing in their logic, and leave the user dithering over which one to click, only to find that one, or other, is disabled anyway (without the only enabled button being automatically selected).

In addition, the "No action required" radio button is superfluous to requirements, as if the user could click Submit, without doing anything (which they used to be able to do so), then it is implicit that no action is required.

In summary, there is no need for the radio buttons and they should not exist:

- "No action required" is implicit when the user clicks the Submit button after having done nothing, and;
- "I'm done" is the only choice (if an action has been taken).
- At no time are both buttons enabled, thereby negating their reason for existence.

**"Question"/"Other Answers"**

WRT to the "Question"/"Other Answers" tabs, it was already possible to view the question of the first post answer under review, by simply scrolling down. Now you have to click another button. The other answers weren't visible though, so the ability to now view them might be an improvement, I guess.

#### Conclusion

UI/UX improvements are meant to make things easier, and not require *even more* effort and induce RSI. As a result, reviews now take longer to perform, which impacts on people's time and reduces workflow efficiency. These additional clicks quickly add up, especially when doing multiple reviews, across multiple sites. If people were being paid (by the hour) to do reviews then they might not mind so much about the time each review takes, but as this is an unpaid voluntary task, it's not a good idea to put reviewers off, as this will lead to more full queues, and people will not then be able to suggest edits, or what-have-you.

---

<sup>1</sup> However, that would mean that the UI element would have to change, from two radio buttons (before anything was done), to a single checkbox (after some change has occurred), and obviously changing UI elements, in the middle of a workflow, is extremely bad practice.

Comment: I did write a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/8892/stack-exchange-one-click-reviews) to make it so that clicking a review action will immediately submit the review. This restores the behavior of the old review UI.

Comment: We're planning to rework these queues with explicit actions to be taken rather than just tracking interactions.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

In the Close Votes queue, the currently voted/flagged-for close reasons are visible close to the top of the review task screen, which is awesome to be able to see.

But in [this particular review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/77143) (now completed), the close reasons that were shown were duplicated. Here's a screenshot of what I saw when I started the review:

[image: Duplicated close reasons]

At the time that I had started the review on the post, it had 4 close votes. I imagine the reason it was counted as 5 (the number at the end of each close reason in the list) was because of a flag, but that's pure speculation on my part without being a moderator and being able to see the flags on the post.

Speculation aside, the close reasons being duplicated in the list is still a bug. Could this be fixed?

Comment: They're not _exactly_ duplicated.  One has a comma after "network", the other does not.  There's a certain reputation threshold where we don't let users flag with the individual community-specific options and they instead just have the default option (`reasonId = 1`).  These are technically distinct reasons that can't be grouped together because reasons. :/

Comment: @BrianNickel Interesting... And unfortunate. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Most of the users voting or flagging chose the canned reason, while one user either voted with a custom reason or flagged with the "Blatantly off-topic" separate option.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As far as I know (and see according the results on the page) filtering all in the queue behaves like filtering nothing, but the button in latter case says "Filtered" which is not actually true.

> [image: Filter all]

> [image: Filter none]

Same behavior after adding only space(s) into Tags box.

Comment: Thanks for the report! The first part, if I'm understanding you correctly, is by design. When nothing is selected from the filter list, you're removing each of those close reasons from the filter. That's why the default is having them all selected - it's not filtered if everything's selected. For the latter half of your report, I have to dig in a bit more to the tags issue before I can weigh in there.

Comment: @kristinalustig I know that all empty checkboxed work as all checked. The issue is why text on the button says "Filtered" in latter case if it works same as not filtered?

Comment: It doesn't work the same - if all checkboxes are empty, you are filtering out every item that meets one of those criteria. No duplicates, no "Not suitable for this site", etc.

Comment: @kristinalustig if you're right why I see [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLxH1.png)? Filter already applied of course.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. We fixed this and made it so that if you deselect everything, it just defaults back to no filter. Also fixed the tag space issue. Thank you! The fix will be out in the next build, either today or Monday.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Please move the banner shown directly after completion of an audit to be more consistent with the layout during review.

During review all actions including moving to the next review are shown in a small box on the right:

[image]

While after review the action to move to the next review is now on the other side of the screen at the far top left:

[image]

I guess this is because it's the same banner which is shown when looking at historical reviews, but it's disruptive to reviewing and inconsistent with the review layout. Perhaps this is clear on a SD/HD screens, but on a UHD screen screen I had to go looking for the button.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. The slowing down here is intentional - we want folks to pause and review the result of their audits, positive or negative, so the button being here next to the message is the place that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

At [cs.SE] there is still no option to vote on the answer in "first post review queue".

When switching from "Question" to "Answer" the Actions pop-up disappears, which prevents this use case: Question is good, I vote up, answer is good, I vote up and submit "I'm done".

In other queues, when there is preview of "other answers" e.g. from Low quality or Late answer, voting is also unavailable.

Voting at Close review also makes sense to me, if it was a mistake to put question there, it might be salvaged, edited or cleared. If someone understood the question, giving a good answer and addressing ambiguities (e.g.) in the comments, any additional action requires opening a new tab. It cannot be the same one, because the reviewing process skips the current item then.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We've added in voting in all places in review queues, so you can vote on whichever questions and answers you'd like. This fix will be in the next build, either later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There are two types of Actions box. One for a wide screen, and another for the narrow (e.g. smartphone) screen:

> [image: wide screen]

> [image: narrow screen]

On the desktop browser you can switch from one to another by changing the window width. And in that case currently selected option is not synchronized among different types of boxes.

My suggestion is that these boxes should use only single active option that is synchronized for both types. I.e. changing the value inside one box should reflect the value in another when I changed the screen width.

Comment: This will be added in the next build.

Comment: @BrianNickel glad to hear you Brian! I'm still using iPad SE app and waiting for continue of development and your great work and answers! Thank you for the current fix as well.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

According to observable behavior filtering for tags uses max 3 **different** tags. E.g. I've entered more than 3 same tags and the result only shows one instead of many:

> [image]

So I'm suggesting adding the word "different" to the description.

Comment: Or “distinct”. But this behavior is the same for questions or edits to those (max 5 tags), search, and tag watching. Identical tags get merged into one, because tags have set semantics, implicitly.

Comment: I fixed this a while back to use the standard tag editor.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Perhaps users would appreciate seeing the total count of review items in the queue for their selected filter?

[image]

This would effectively change the review queues from a black-box to a white-box. The same functionality already exists for regular post searches.

[image]

Conceivably this would allow tag enthusiasts and chat room users to have a grasp on the real volume of expertise reviews that are needed and organize accordingly.

Comment: This idea was indicated in the designs as well. _Unfortunately_, the way review queues are currently built, it is not trivial to determine the number of review tasks that match a filter or importantly the number of those tasks that are actually reviewable by the current user.  The next phases of this project are more architecture-oriented, which will hopefully allow us to revisit this.

Answer (score 2):

When a review queue has a long description, the 'Recent reviewers' label in the right column wraps around as well, as can be seen on [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review):

[image]

Not a big deal, but having more consistency is always an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

> More context - Users can now toggle between the review task and the necessary context (original question, answers, and comments) on the task page to assist in making educated decisions on a task. No need to open new browser tabs!

Why is the question itself hidden in a modal when reviewing an answer, when it's important to know that before doing a sensible review. Yes, I know, it's a click away, but *I didn't have to click before* to get the question. This is important in both late answers and low quality review queues (while I'm good at identifying spam, I'm terrible at identifying not-spam when the question asks for it).

Please, bring back the question on all views that review an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the First Posts queue on AU, clicking "Filter":

[image]

And then selecting "Clear" without doing anything else seems to skip the review task *without* giving feedback, even "Skip".  I managed to do the same with an MSE suggested-edit review task a couple seconds ago.

Answer (score 1):

I see a conflict in Phase 3:

[image: conflict in phase 3, will it be SO only or network wide?]

On one hand you say both changes are SO only, on the other hand you say "All network sites". Which hand will it be?

Comment: All changes from Phase 1 and 2 will roll out network wide. The two remaining SO-only queues will also be rolled out at that time.

Comment: Those queues only exist on SO.

Comment: @animuson that's not clear at all that the "Where" refers to all previous phases. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Makyen I know, hence the confusion. If they exist only on SO how will the change be shipped to all sites? (No need to answer, animuson already did)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I just encountered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360717/295232) in the [Reopen Votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/77050). Presumably it got there after @rene's edit ([9 seconds after it was closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/360717/timeline)). Yet while reviewing it said (and still said after revisiting the page before the review was completed; now it's gone) "No changes to display.":

[image]

(It could very well be that this is unrelated to the UI changes, but if you are working on this now, perhaps it's an easy fix.)

Comment: Aaaargh, ninja'd again!

Comment: I'll look into this.  Off the top of my head, I'd say we render the revision tab if there were edits after the closure, but the diff can cover multiple revisions, which may undo each other.  We should be able to detect that the diff has no changes and hide the tab.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  If there's no changes to display (because the diff is empty), we won't show the revision tab.  Interestingly, it's not just rollbacks that can cause this state but quick edits like the one you saw.  We omit any edits that occurred in the 10 seconds after closure from counting, I assume because we don't count them as edits in response to closure.  Changing that would be a bigger and more philosophical conversation.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

First seen in the [Reopen Votes queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen):  If you click “Following” on a task to unfollow the question, and then submit the “Next” action, the Stacks error message doesn’t go away:

[image]

Minor annoyance, but it goes away when you move to the Stats or History, so can we make it disappear when you move to another task?

Comment: I wouldnt consider this an error message, more a notification.

Comment: Related: [Automatically dismiss the “This post has been deleted” banner in triage review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403730/1364007) - these banners should go whenever the page doesn't relate to the banner any more.

Comment: I think this is an old bug: [Automatically dismiss 'Please consider adding a comment' message when loading next review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320760/295232)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Some screenshots and text seem to be swapping places in the VLQ posts queue:

[image]

On [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/77170) review, Question tab.  The actual post looks like this:

[image]

What happened there?

Comment: Do you mean the placement of the "The screenshot"? I took me a while to figure out the difference between the two images. Maybe add block quote to give the image a border as the amount of white is a *little* confusing, as to where the screenshots begin and end, and which text belongs to the screenshot and which to your answer. Or maybe, I'm just getting old... :-)

Comment: It’s not swapping. It’s actually rendered the same way. The image is _inline_, as there is not paragraph break between “This screenshot:” and the image. In review, the post width is just wider, so the screenshot fits into one line with the text, but outside of review, the post is not wide enough for that.

Comment: As mentioned above, this is an artifact of the screenshot being cropped in a way that makes it seem like it's above the "This screenshot" text, when in this circumstance it's actually to the right of it.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When suggested edit already reviewed by me, but not yet applied to the post I can still see the `Edit (1)` link under the post. Clicking the link opens popup:

> [image: not relevant header]

The header (whatever on the top of popup) is not relevant for me since I can't do anything with this edit anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the report - fixed this! Fix will be out either later today or tomorrow in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

> No need to open new browser tabs!

I appreciate the thought behind this, however, as long as the review process puts fake work in front of me, I think I am always going to open a new tab. It's how I know the review is fake and I don't need to spend time reading or thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Another bug on narrow screens.

This is *similar* to - but not the same as - [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361456/284827) (which is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and seemed to affect Chrome and Edge but not Firefox).

When shown a low quality posts review task (and possibly other review task types) where the title for the post under review is long (this doesn't seem to be an issue if joined with backslashes, e.g. `path1\path2\path3\...\pathN`), there is no wrapping of the title text - **and** this causes the review actions to not be visible without zooming out.

For instance, [this review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28490756) is for [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66541562/1364007) to the question [Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64011421/1364007)

In the default view, the review actions options are not visible and they were not visible after scrolling down slightly (though they *may* have been visible if I'd scrolled down to the very bottom of the page - I should really have skipped the review so I could investigate further):

[image]

One when zoomed out are the actions visible:

[image]

This affects (at least) Chrome 88.0.4324.190, Edge 85.0.564.67, Firefox 86.0 (all on Windows 10), and Chrome 88.0.4324.181 on Android 10.

The behaviour is confusing and it made me wonder if I'd reached the current quota of reviews (or if I'd been review-suspended).

---

Upon using the HTML inspector, I found that the CSS for the text in the `<a>` anchor inherits

```
overflow-wrap: break-word
```

from `h3`. According to [the MDN page for `overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap):

> The `overflow-wrap` CSS property applies to inline elements, setting whether the browser should insert line breaks within an otherwise unbreakable string to prevent text from overflowing its line box.

> Note: In contrast to `word-break`, `overflow-wrap` will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

Changing the value of `word-break` from `break-word` to `anywhere` 'fixes' this issue but may well cause other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Another narrow screens bug - some of which is browser-specific

Posts with long titles can fail to be wrapped in the history view, causing a horizontal scroll bar to be required/shown.

This relates to [this first bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361456/284827) (now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) and [this second bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361890/284827) (with no [status] tag) (both regarding long question titles on narrow screens).

*Note: To minimise the vertical width of this answer I've resized the windows to the smallest vertical size to demonstrate the bug. The bug is still present if the windows have a larger vertical height (e.g. on a phone in portrait orientation).*

---

**Reviews on** [PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPipes.php on line 140.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51610323/1364007):

- In Chrome 88.0.4324.190 and Edge 85.0.564.67 (both on Windows 10), and Chrome 88.0.4324.181 on Android 10 - no text wrapping:

  [image]
- In Firefox 86.0 (on Windows 10) - text successfully wrapped:

  [image]

---

**Reviews on** [Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64011421/1364007):

- In Chrome 88.0.4324.190 and Edge 85.0.564.67 (both on Windows 10), and Chrome 88.0.4324.181 on Android 10 - no text wrapping:

  [image]
- In Firefox 86.0 (on Windows 10) - no text wrapping:

  [image]

---

Other pages that have reviews with neatly-wrappable titles reflow nicely for any screen size - this appears to be related to very long titles which contains 'words' which are not allowed to be broken up by the browser.

As with my remark at the end of [the second bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361890/284827), it looks like changing the value of [the `overflow-wrap` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) to `anywhere` 'fixes' this problem but could introduce others.

Answer (score 0):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Consider removing the hyperlinks from the canned review text (in the pop-up window) *during the review process*. I never want to click on the links when selecting the item; I only want to select the item. Having the links there means that there are places on the screen that I never want to click on.

Comment: I agree that they can be annoying, especially on mobile. I end up getting directed instead of selecting a close reason as well every now and then. But I do understand the usefullness these links provide to new(er) reviewers. Hence I disagree they should be removed.

Comment: The text of the links is pretty descriptive. Maybe it could be a toggle like the ads are. Or maybe it's just another userscript to make SE more useful.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve this without making it less useful to newer reviewers.  I'm tossing an upvote on this for the general concept that I constantly misclick them when I'm on mobile, but I think just removing them isn't the right solution (if there's any way to disable the browser redirecting nearby touches onto the link, that might help).

Comment: We want to retain these links for newer users who might need the links for additional context. We may consider other solutions in the future but for now I'll status-declined this particular request. Thank you for reporting the issue!

Comment: Thank you for considering it. I would just suggest that linking terms like "reputation" or "Ask Question" or "vote up" doesn't really add much value. Besides, reviewing queues is a privilege that starts halfway towards the "established user" level, beyond several other privileges, so I would say that the links aren't providing very much value, as the target audience is already fairly established in SE. @kristinalustig

Comment: My point is that the links are perfectly valuable to the recipient of the stock text, and not particularly useful to the reviewer.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

I found a weird color issue for review pages on my phone (Android 10, Chrome).

The orange/brown background color for selected tab (SO logo/topline at the page header are also affected) is darker for "Stats" tab and brighter for other tabs:

> [image: Different brown/orange]

Affects all SO family sites: English and internationals.

Not reproducible on:

- desktop browser (neither Chrome, nor Firefox) on Windows 10.
- mobile Firefox on the same Android device

BTW I got a tangible delay while loading "Stats" page on every browser/device.

Comment: Are you sure the tab isn’t just selected or focused with a default blue selection color? Actually, on a second look, the entire web page content looks desaturated in the middle screenshot, not just the tab. Look at the Stack Overflow logo or your profile picture…

Comment: @SebastianSimon tab bg-color is the first thing what I looked at, the second was a logo, then horizontal (orange) line right below the URL. The latter two are described in my post. The "Learn more" link also looks darker for the middle image. Seems you're right about whole page desaturation, but I can't get the reason for that behavior.

Comment: Neither Brian nor I are able to reproduce this color desaturation issue or find any reason why it might be happening on that particular page. So, while that is status-norepro, you're right that there's a query that takes for-e-ver on the stats page. We're taking a look into that now. Thanks for the heads up.