# Case inconsistency with titles of review queues

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, review, capitalization

There is inconsistency with review queue titles' case. On the [Review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) page, all of titles' first characters are only capital letters.

> [image: main review page with sentence case titles]

When navigating to individual review page, such as [Suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) and [Low quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts), the titles are Pascal Case. But for the [Close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close) and [Reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) the titles are in the correct case.

> [image: individual review queue pages with title case]

Can the wording case be consistent for all the review titles?

Comment: I think the inconsistency is there only in Meta SE.

Answer (score 9):

This is related to the changes being put out regarding the review queues - [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues)

As you can see, the first phase only impacts close/reopen queues and we won't be rolling out changes to the others until Phases 2 or 3.

> |  | What | Where | When |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | **Phase 1** | • Home page (/review) • Close and reopen votes queue • Stats/History view • Steward badge | Meta Stack Exchange Meta Stack Overflow | January 28, 2021 |
> | **Phase 2** | • *Changes from Phase 1* • Suggested edits queue • Low quality posts queue • First posts queue • Late answers queue | SuperUser Ask Ubuntu | February 16, 2021 |
> | **Phase 3** | • *Changes from Phase 1 + 2* • Triage queue (SO only) • Help and improvement queue (SO only) | All network sites | February 23, 2021 |

So, as these changes roll out, you should see the case change on these menus.

Comment: So that would make this [tag:status-planned]?

Comment: I hesitate to put a tag on it at all, which is why I haven't. It's not really a bug at all and you could as easily say that it's by-design.

Comment: Yeah that's also true. But it would be good for the CM response percentage ;)

Comment: @Catija Seems Phase 3 was shipped and FR is resolved, good to add status-completed tag to the post.

Comment: Looks like this change has since been rolled out to those pages, so I'm marking it as [status-completed].