# Review audit formatting bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

Some days ago on Mathematics StackExchange I failed the review audit. The system said I need to pay more attention. [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33156/811225) the result of paying attention :)

> [image: 1]

Description: The line escape character `\n` wasn't formatted correctly.

My question: Is this bug a status complete yet and, did other users find this error?

Comment: If this is with the old review UI, it probably won't be fixed, as it's slated to be replaced in three days.

Comment: @bad_coder I made it small, just click on the image, it'll show the original resolution....Ohh also, if that doesnt work, remove the 'm' from the suffix of image name

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog You meant [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/826559) right....I can't find anything about review audits....so it might not suffer a UI change (not sure). And the replacement scheduled in 3 days is for SO....my bug was found on Math...Anyways, if you face a review audit, try failing it and see if it persists. Thank you !