# Edit-rejection string "edit does not improve the quality of the post" needs to be added to Transifex

Tags: bug, review, localization

At [this](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/258383) suggested edit on SO in Spanish, the edit-rejection reason:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

Is in English:

[image]

And it doesn't appear to be in [the traducir website](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=This%20edit%20does%20not%20improve).  Same for [SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/258389) in [Russian](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=This%20edit%20does%20not%20improve).  Can it be added, so we'll be able to translate it?

Answer (score 1):

The string is in traducir now for SO in Spanish: https://es.traducir.win/strings/17317

So you're able to translate it.

Already translated for ruSO: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16150