# The checkbox on the review page history tab is fully selected on Firefox browser

Tags: bug, review, design, firefox, review-history

The checkbox on the review page history tab is fully selected on Firefox browser. There is no issue in the Chrome browser.

**StackApps:**

> [image]

**Stack Overflow:**

> [image]

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 86.0 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (64-bit) |

---

**Expected behaviour: (from Google Chrome)**

[image]

Comment: FYI: I think this should posted in the [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/284827) question - as a [bug]. The OP of that question, [Lisa Park](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/452001/lisa-park) wrote "*Please leave any feedback or bug reports related to this release below this post.*".

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Nightly 88.0a1, but only when the page is being redirected to the history with skipped reviews. The checkbox indeed has a custom style (it has `appearance: none;` with two additional vendor prefixes). The `:checked` state has `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,`…`");`. Maybe it doesn’t render fast enough, or rendering is blocked, while the page is being redirected.