# Check mark does not render when the "Show skipped reviews" is checked at least in the "My reviews" tab under the Suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, user-interface

> [image]
> Issue (taken here on MSE)

> [image]
> Same issue taken on another site

> [image]
> Expected result (different queue, same browser)

The visual glitch in the checkbox *(shown in the top two images)* affects at least the [*My reviews* tab under suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history).

Re [this related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361887/289905) (issue affecting Firefox and not Chrome): all the above screenshots are taken using Firefox, and the last screenshot as shown renders correctly, so it's possibly **not** a browser issue.

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [The checkbox on the review page history tab is fully selected on Firefox browser](/q/361887/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon: works fine also on Firefox as shown in the last image.