# Please make suggested edit review tasks wider

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I find it difficult to review edits when the prose is displayed is narrow columns:

[image]

It would make it so much easier if the width of the allowed space could be used for the actual review, instead of having 1/3 of the screen allocated to review options. Something like this:

[image]

It may not matter much for sites where there's not a lot of code blocks, but for Stack OverFlow, the narrow columns forces a lot of scrolling. Both horizontal and vertical scrolling.

This is my entire screen:

[image]

Comment: Do note that [this was already suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361376/369802) (another one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361331/369802)) when the design change was introduced several months ago, and at that point, it was [tag:status-declined], the reason for which is stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/361378#comment1207410_361378) on yet another answer requesting more space.

Comment: Oh. That is unfortunate. The first suggestion doesn't propose a solution. The last comment is stating that the page should not go beyond 1100px. Which I don't suggest. I'd just want for the actions to be re-arranged on the page. The middle one kind of suggests the same though without saying where the buttons could go.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361376/369802, which is the first link in my previous comment, last sentence: "Can we move the actions box back on top,"... That seems to be the exact same suggestion as you did here?

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. I missed that. What now? I suppose it's not possible to close a post against an Answer. I only really want this to apply for suggested edits. The other review queues seems to have the prose be just as wide as a normal post, where the actions area just seems to substitute the right sidebar.

Comment: What now? Just note that the previous ones asking for change all ended up with status-declined, and comments stating that it's not something that was likely to change at that time/soon. As for the duplicate, sometimes questions like this do end up closed as duplicates (because it's easier to have feedback on new changes in one place), but I *personally* think 7 months is a safe moment to say "hey people talked about this before but it's okay to have a separate feature request for it, it's no longer a 'new' change". Others may disagree, in which case they can vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Another option is to display them one on top of the other so both posts can make use of the full width. Granted, if there isn't enough vertical real estate devoted to each, that is a similar problem. Maybe it could be made responsive...

Comment: @ColleenV That is an option, but I'm not a fan of that. Seeing a diff is easier when you can see both of the version next to each other. If one needs to scroll past the first post to see the other, it will not prevent scrolling and I think harder to see the differences. I use "side by side" all the time. And "side by side markdown" to spot subtle or cheeky stuff.

Comment: @Unconsidered I think on a vertical format like a phone placing the scrollable panes on top of each other would be preferable, but on a wider screen they should be side by side and use a good portion of the available width, i.e. be responsive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues)

Comment: @Luuklag No. It does not. This is a separate feature-request. See the comments at the top. Closing this post basically puts an end to the hope of getting it implemented.

Comment: @ColleenV yeah, would be ideal - and done quite easily with `@media` queries

Comment: Due to the "report any further issues after the 10th in a new request" [**note**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/282094) I'm going to leave this open.

Comment: @Rob you would be right if this was a new issue, which it clearly isn't.

Comment: @Luuklag, 5 pages of 123 answers. You couldn't have edited your autocomment (or [additional comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369662/please-make-suggested-edit-review-tasks-wider?noredirect=1#comment1233713_369662)) to include a direct link, and you mention "right and clearly"; so I won't say that's helpful. --- It's a request to rereview the prior decline and the OP's claim that it isn't a duplicate. My [comment passed review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/79357).

Comment: I must also point out the reasons given as to why this change will not be implemented are complete BS if you ask me. From the technical standpoint - definitely, this is no more involved than 2 lines of CSS literally. "Philosophically" does not make sense either given that Aaron's team is working towards *moving from* fixed-width non-responsive pages which would be in direct conflict the "philosophy" of keeping pages 1100px max-width...

Comment: @Rob at the time unfortunately no, I couldn't from my mobile device and there was also no need as Tink already linked to the specific answer in her first comment. Also this post doesn't A: state that this is a request to review the previous decline and B: does nothing to adres the objections raised by staff the first time around.

Comment: The comment by staff on the other post (both of the Answers) is explicitly about not widening the screen to beyond 1100px. This feature-request does not ask for that. It merely asks to move the buttons. Staff also says "we'll possibly revisit this sometime in the future". Perhaps it's time to revisit this.

Comment: At narrow widths they pin the actions to the bottom of the page. I'd be happy with them doing that at all widths but I don't know how many people would agree with me since so many folks hate the pinned top nav.