# Bad edit approval

Tags: support, suggested-edits

An edit on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) was *approved*, but how? [The Approval page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/335648) currently shows two rejects and only one approval. (It does not help that the two rejects are by top users on the site and the approval by someone with much lower reputation.)

How was this edit approved?

[The answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) noted in the comments says

> Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it.

So I am even more confused as there are two reject votes. So it should have been rejected by that logic - the logic I would hope for is a net score - so currently one for reject at the time the edit was accepted.

Comment: Seems odd if intended by the system, needs changing. Don't know what yop is, "Ye Olde Privileged/Programmers" perhaps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) "The owner of a post [...] may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post."

Comment: That edit was approved by the user who *owned* that post

Comment: @francescalus No for two reasons 1) That says "Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it." 2) There are more rejects than approvals

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Ah that makes sense but the UI should make that clearer.

Comment: The bug is in the wording which does not mention the OP's ability to override the actions on their own post. This is indeed confusing, but that's how the system works and there's no bug in it.

Comment: It should say, e.g. "user224124 reviewed this 1 hour ago: Override (Approve)".

Comment: "If you believe the community decision on a suggested edit to one of your posts was wrong, you can override the outcome in certain cases." (from the same Q&A) covers what happens after two reject votes.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, do I also recall correctly that the "post owner background" highlighting should also apply?

Comment: @francescalus that's something different, but yeah think there is such a bug report.

Comment: I [reported the issue of author highlight as an answer to the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361916/377214) at the time the review UI was changed to its current form, as the old review UI *did* highlight it, but it got no response. @francescalus

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard That is actually technically feasible, as the database review task result types (internal numbers used to indicate review types) are different for overrides as opposed to normal reviews.

Comment: @Sonic that is lucky, almost as lucky as getting a response from staff when posting bug report or feature request under a fresh announcement. Only few get any attention, usually all thrown to their "backlog".

Comment: @francescalus I [reposted the answer as a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388257/add-back-the-highlight-on-the-authors-name-on-suggested-edit-reviews-to-their-o) as per staff instructions.