# The visual hint for a vote is less visible than for a retracted vote on Chrome for iOS

Tags: feature-request, design, voting, ios, mobile-chrome

Problem: The visual hint for a vote is less visible than for a retracted vote on Chrome for iOS. I sometimes have to revote and reretract to understand whether I did what I want (voted or retracted).

Feature request: just don't show any visual hints for retracted votes. I.e.,  the button should appear as if the user didn't click on it.

Problem demonstration:

[image]

Comment: It's due to the hover style, which you can verify by using a desktop browser. Part of the issue is with your mobile browser continuing to indicate that one's hovering over the button after it's tapped.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, maybe even of one of the answers on the original announcement. I kept on upvoting this one spam post by accident (which I mentioned on the duplicate which I can't find).

Comment: @Laurel If it is a duplicate of a really old answer to an announcement, which doesn't have a response, then the team [has indicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/361916#comment1294485_360198) that they prefer people repost them as new questions; as such, if that's the case, it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

To be sure of your choice (voted or not), you can simply click somewhere else.

When you click on one of those buttons once (when cancelling a vote) on a touchscreen device, the button behaves as if you were hovering it on a computer (without the guidance text). Clicking away from the button will make it behave as if the mouse has moved.

[image: Gif of the described behaviour (on iPhone)]

Here, I first click on the upvote button once (number goes to 1), click it again (blue circle with black arrow), and finally click away (goes back to normal).